# How to prepend all list elements into another list

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge two lists in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python)

How can I prepend list elements into another list?

```
A = ['1', '2']
B = ['3', '4']
A.append(B)
print A
```

returns

```
['1', '2', ['3', '4']]
```

How can I make it

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
A.extend(B)
```

or

```
A += B
```

This text added to let me post this answer.

Comment: Is there another way to pad the anser with redundant text to meet the minimum-limit of the characters?

Comment: I mean there was `<img>`, but it seems not working anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

`list.extend`, for example, in your case, `A.extend(B)`.

Answer (score -2):

this can also be done as

```
for s in B: 
    A.append(B)
```

of course `A.extend(B)` does the same work but using `append` we need to add in the above f