# What is the fastest way to merge two lists in python?

Tags: python, performance, list, merge

Given,

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
```

What is the **fastest way** to achieve the following in python?

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Please note that there can be many ways to merge two lists in python.
I am looking for the most time-efficient way.

I tried the following and here is my understanding.

CODE

```
import time

c = list(range(1,10000000))
c_n = list(range(10000000, 20000000))

start = time.time()
c = c+c_n
print len(c)
print time.time() - start

c = list(range(1,10000000))
start = time.time()
for i in c_n:
    c.append(i)
print len(c)
print time.time() - start

c = list(range(1,10000000))
start = time.time()
c.extend(c_n)
print len(c)
print time.time() - start
```

OUTPUT

```
19999999
0.125061035156
19999999
1.02858018875
19999999
0.03928399086
```

So, if someone does not bother reusing list_1/list_2 in the question then **extend** is the way to go. On the other hand, **"+"** is the fastest way.

I am not sure about other options though.

Comment: See this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python

Comment: You're not really merging here, you're concatenating... Is that really what you want?  What should you get with `list1 = [1,2,3,5]; list2 = [4,5,6,7]`?

Comment: You can't get any faster than `list_1 + list_2`

Comment: The extend is the fastest method to merge lists.

Answer (score 34):

You can just use concatenation:

```
list = list_1 + list_2
```

If you don't need to keep list_1 around, you can just modify it:

```
list_1.extend(list_2)
```

Comment: What happens if list_1 is empty (or if list_2 is empty or both)?

Comment: @hepcat72 Nothing special, it will produce the correct result.

Comment: What's the correct result? If list_1 is empty and list_2 contained a single string "a", would list contain [undef,"a"] or just ["a"]?

Comment: `undef`? There is no such thing. `[] + ["a"] == ["a"]`. If you add a list with zero items and a list with one item, you'll end up with a list containing one item, naturally, not two.

Comment: I'm a python newb. Thanks for the explanation. Just trying to figure out how python works.

Comment: No problem, in the future, just try your own example in the Python console. "Try it and see"

Comment: What if you're trying to merge half of list_1 and half of list_2 in one list called list_3? Will + still work?

Comment: What is the result when the two lists have a common value?, will the value be repeated in the resulting list?

Answer (score 16):

I tested out several ways to merge two lists (see below) and came up with the following order after running each several times to normalize the cache changes (which make about a 15% difference).

```
import time
c = list(range(1,10000000))
c_n = list(range(10000000, 20000000))
start = time.time()
*insert method here* 
print (time.time()-start)
```

- Method 1: `c.extend(c_n)`

  - Representative result: 0.11861872673034668
- Method 2: `c += c_n`

  - Representative result: 0.10558319091796875
- Method 3: `c = c + c_n`

  - Representative result: 0.25804924964904785
- Method 4: `c = [*c, *c_n]`

  - Representative result: 0.22019600868225098

**Conclusion**
    Use `+=` or `.extend()` if you want to merge in place. They are significantly faster.

Comment: I tested it with python 3.8 and confirmed Kiran's results. Note that method 2 uses INPLACE_ADD bytecode instruction, meaning it operates in place (on the same memory), hence why it is faster than method 3, which uses BINARY_ADD

Comment: @Almenon how can I see the bytecode instructions being used?

Comment: @Jonathan see https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html

Answer (score 13):

If you are using python 3, there is one more way to do this and a little bit faster (tested only on python 3.7)

```
[*list1, *list2]
```

*Benchmark*

```
from timeit import timeit
x = list(range(10000))
y = list(x)

def one():
    x + y

def two():
    [*x, *y]

print(timeit(one, number=1000, globals={'x':x, 'y': y}))
print(timeit(two, number=1000, globals={'x':x, 'y': y}))
0.10456193100253586
0.09631731400440913
```

Comment: Interesting, I got similar numbers to you for lists of size 10k elements, but when I went up to lists with 100k elements `one` was faster (at least using 3.6)

Comment: Hmm, I just tried with 100k elements, result is the second one is still faster.

Comment: I'm on 3.6 though, so that may be related

Comment: Yeah
one: 40.26142632599658
two: 29.216321185995184

this is the result for 1 million items, the second one is significantly faster,

Comment: Laptop is falling over trying to run it with 1mil items, will take your word for it :)

Answer (score 11):

`list_1 + list_2` does it. Example -

```
>>> list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
>>> list_1 + list_2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

c=a+b
print(c)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 >>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In the above code "+" operator is used to concatenate the 2 lists into a single list.

**ANOTHER SOLUTION:**

```
 a=[1,2,3]
 b=[4,5,6]
 c=[] #Empty list in which we are going to append the values of list (a) and (b)

 for i in a:
     c.append(i)
 for j in b:
     c.append(j)

 print(c)
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way appears to be:

```py
list1 + list2
```

---

`benchmark.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from timeit import timeit

count = 1_000_000
list_size = 1_000

l1 = list(range(list_size))
l2 = list(range(list_size))


def plus():
    return l1 + l2


def plusequal():
    lst = []
    lst += l1
    lst += l2
    return lst


def asterisk():
    return [*l1, *l2]


print('#', sys.version.replace('\n', ''))
for fn in (plus, plusequal, asterisk):
    print(fn.__qualname__, timeit(fn, number=count,
                                  globals={'l1': l1, 'l2': l2}))
```

Results:

```
$ for v in 8 9 10 11; do python3.$v benchmark.py ; done
# 3.8.16 (default, Jan 19 2023, 02:07:34) [GCC 12.2.0]
plus 2.3145008360006614
plusequal 2.388007382996875
asterisk 2.4057720839991816
# 3.9.16 (main, Jan 19 2023, 02:11:50) [GCC 12.2.0]
plus 2.410123729998304
plusequal 2.810086893001426
asterisk 2.822675076997257
# 3.10.11 (main, May  7 2023, 23:10:58) [GCC 13.1.1 20230429]
plus 2.5304620300012175
plusequal 2.8561974199983524
asterisk 2.813428355999349
# 3.11.3 (main, Jun  5 2023, 09:32:32) [GCC 13.1.1 20230429]
plus 2.473347854000167
plusequal 2.8089449279978
asterisk 2.81812875399919
```