# How to join two lists in python?

Tags: python, list, join, append

I want two lists inside one list:

```
x = [1,2]
y = [3,4]
```

I need them to turn out like:

```
z = [[1,2][3,4]]
```

But I have no idea how to do that.
Thanks so much for your consideration and help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to merge two lists in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044508/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-merge-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul If I'm not mistaken, this question is slightly different from the question you've posted above.

Answer (score 6):

Make a new list which contains the first two lists.

```
z = [x, y]
```

This will make each element of `z` a reference to the original list. If you don't want that to happen you can do the following.

```
from copy import copy
z = [copy(x), copy(y)]
print z
```

Comment: you just created references to x and y, any changes to either would mean the list of lists would change

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for pointing that out. I overlooked it. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want references to the original list objects:

```
z = [x[:], y[:]]
```

Comment: Although this isn't explicit and readable, this approach is really interesting!

Comment: @ssundarraj it's doing the same thing as your answer, except in a more succinct manner. In my mind this is just as explicit and readable as yours, without the extra import and lines of code.

Comment: @MattDMo Agreed! It's very succinct. It's less explicit though. That's all I meant to convey. I really like this approach. I will probably be using it myself.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
 >>> x = [1, 2]
 >>> y = [3, 4]
 >>> z = [x, y]
 >>> print("z = ", z)
 z =  [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: except that `z` contains *references* to `x` and `y`, not their actual *values*. If `x` or `y` are changed somewhere down the line, `z` will change as well, which likely isn't the intention of the programmer. This causes hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [ 1, 2 ]
y = [ 2, 3 ]
z =[]
z.append(x)
z.append(y)
print z

output:
[[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```