# Concatenate each line of two arrays into a single one

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have two arrays a and b.

```
a.shape is (95, 300)
b.shape is (95, 3)
```

How can I obtain a new array c by concatenating each of the 95 lines ?

```
c.shape is (95, 303)
```

Comment: which datatype(s)/libraries are you suing? are they tuples? are they dt from a gis library? what are the rules for combining the data structures?

Comment: Take a look are the following:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [`hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> a = np.ones((95, 300))
>>> b = np.ones((95, 3)) * 2
>>> a.shape
(95, 300)
>>> b.shape
(95, 3)
>>> c = np.hstack((a,b))
>>> c
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
>>> c.shape
(95, 303)
```

Comment: yes, it did the trick... too bad I can't approve it fast enough