# How to merge item in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, merge

I have problem with list in python. When I print "list" I have this results:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

So I have two lists in one variable I guess. How can I merge this items to one variable ?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more code for clarity

Comment: A variable (or "name" in python), can only be one object at a time. What you have is a list (or similar) containing two lists, containing 1, 2, 3 and 4, 5, 6 respectively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two lists in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  ,

```
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> result=[]
>>> for i in a:
    result+=i


>>> result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

**OR**

```
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> sum(a, [])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**OR**

```
>>> a1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a2
[4, 5, 6]
>>> [item for item in itertools.chain(a1, a2)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This could be simplified to just `result = sum(a, [])`.

Comment: Although it is important to note that this is probably rather slow.

Answer (score 2):

I would do, using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from%5fiterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4 , 5, 6]]
>>> a = itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If:

```
returnList = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

You can very easily do:

```
>>> returnList = [j for i in returnList for j in i]
```

Or:

```
>>> returnList = [j for i in returnList for j in i]
```

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
>>> returnList = reduce(lambda i,j: i+j, returnList)
```

Both will return: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Ok but what I must replace with my variable returnList ?

Comment: @user3531797, `a` is what you replace

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['0', '1', '2'], ['3', '4', '5']]

def merge_list(l):
    temp = []
    for i in l:
        for j in i:
            temp.append(j)
    return temp

print merge_list(l)
```

**Result**

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: Input and result are same ?

Comment: Yeah didn't even notice...returned input instead of temp...whoops. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

[Merge 2 list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python)

```
listtwo = [8,9,0]
listone = [1,2,3,4,5]
mergedlist = listone + listtwo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I collect some of the solution and just try timeit:

Here is my snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def f1(List):
    x = []
    [ x.extend(y) for y in List ]
    return x

def f2(List):
    return sum(List, [])

def f3(List):
    temp = []
    for i in List:
        for j in i:
            temp.append(j)
    return temp

def f4(List):
    result=[]
    for i in List:
        result += i
    return result

def f5(List):
    return [j for i in List for j in i]

import cProfile
import itertools
from faker import Faker
from timeit import Timer

s = Faker()
# instead of faker you can use random module
func = [ f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6 ]
Lis = [[ s.random_int(min=1, max=99)
        for x in range(1000) ]
        for x in range(100)]

for fun in func:
    t = Timer(lambda: fun(Lis))
    print fun.__name__, cProfile.run('t.timeit(number=1000)')
```

Output:

```
f1          102011 function calls in 0.701 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.701    0.701 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.040    0.000    0.495    0.000 merge.py:3(f1)
     1000    0.001    0.000    0.495    0.000 merge.py:42(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.701    0.701 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.206    0.206    0.701    0.701 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
   100000    0.455    0.000    0.455    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
f2          3011 function calls in 37.747 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   37.747   37.747 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.003    0.000   37.418    0.037 merge.py:42(<lambda>)
     1000    0.004    0.000   37.415    0.037 merge.py:8(f2)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000   37.747   37.747 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.329    0.329   37.747   37.747 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1000   37.411    0.037   37.411    0.037 {sum}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
f3          100002011 function calls in 28.044 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   28.044   28.044 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000   20.304    0.020   27.676    0.028 merge.py:11(f3)
     1000    0.001    0.000   27.677    0.028 merge.py:42(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000   28.044   28.044 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.367    0.367   28.044   28.044 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
100000000    7.372    0.000    7.372    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
f4          2011 function calls in 0.826 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.826    0.826 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.463    0.000    0.463    0.000 merge.py:18(f4)
     1000    0.001    0.000    0.464    0.000 merge.py:42(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.826    0.826 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.362    0.362    0.826    0.826 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
f5          2011 function calls in 4.608 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    4.608    4.608 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    4.253    0.004    4.253    0.004 merge.py:24(f5)
     1000    0.001    0.000    4.254    0.004 merge.py:42(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    4.608    4.608 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.354    0.354    4.608    4.608 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
```