# Expression I don't understand in code example

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, expression

I came across an expression in one of the pyqtgraph examples which I don't quite understand.

```
spots = [{'pos': pos[:,i], 'data': 1} for i in range(n)] + [{'pos': [0,0], 'data': 1}]
```

In the example `pos` is a two-dimensional NumPy array and `n` a positive integer. 
 
What exactly is the `for` statement doing in inside an expression? 
Also, I might need an explanation for `pos[:,i]`. 
Lastly, how exactly does the `+` operator work with lists? Does it just merge them like `list.extend(anotherlist)`?

Comment: 1. It's a list comprehension 2. That's a list slice 3. Yes. This should give you enough to Google.

Comment: Yes to your last question, it will just merge the lists.

For the for loop in the list  makes it a list comprehension which you can check out here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. 

As for the comma in the list slice. that's advanced indexing in numpy, again you can read up on it here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [list slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation),  [`+` with lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python), Google is everyone's friend.

Comment: Thanks, that's enough to google it

Comment: Tip for the future: multiple questions in one are frowned upon.  Questions are supposed to be useful for the future too, and it's unlikely that someone will have exactly the same three questions that you do, whereas each of your individual questions has been asked and answered on SO many times before.