# Extending list returns None

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to add all elements from one list to another list:

```
list1 = ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'googl']
ok = ['item22']
list1 = list1.extend(ok)
print(list1)
```

But it prints `None`. Why is that?

Comment: is `list1.extend(ok)` ..... not `list1 = list1.extend(ok)`

Comment: you may write better `list1.append(ok)`

Comment: list.extend(object) is a 'void' function.  That is, it does not return any value.  First store the list into a variable.  Call extend on the variable, then pass the variable.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The function [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is an in-place function i.e. it will make the changes to the original list itself. From the docs

> Extend the list by appending all the items in the *given* list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = L.

Since it returns `None`, you should not re-assign it back to the list variable.

You can do

```
list1 = ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'googl']
ok = ['item22']
list1.extend(ok)
```

Then when you print `list1` it will print

```
['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'googl', 'item22']
```

###### Better way

Using `append` as mentioned below is the better way to add a single value to the end of a list.

```
list1 = ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'googl']
ok = 'item22'   # Notice no brackets here
list1.append(ok)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another way, using module **numpy** will do the work https://pypi.org/project/numpy/

Specific in your example it will be look like this:

```
import numpy as np 

list1 = ['hi','how','are','you','googl']
ok = ['item22']
list1 = list(np.append(list1, ok))
print(list1)
```

Comment: This seems like overkill haha

Comment: @BrendanMetcalfe Although seemingly an overkill, this will behave the way OP expected `extend` to