# Python3 how to seperate items in truple

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
list1 = 'it is, a good,day'
```

I need to separate all the parts of the string by the comma : `'it is'`, `'a good'` and  `'day'` and then place `'ouf'` in between each part so it could print `it is ouf a good ouf day`

Note the space after the coma at `', a good'` is there also a way to delete the space only after the comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#join) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> list1 = 'it is, a good,day'
>>> ' ouf '.join(map(str.strip,list1.split(',')))
'it is ouf a good ouf day'
```

Alternatively you can try [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
>>> list1.replace(', ',',').replace(',',' ouf ')
'it is ouf a good ouf day'
```

Considering the edit, I would suggest [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html) module's [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

```
>>> re.sub(r',\s?',' ouf ',list1)
'it is ouf a good ouf day'
```

Comment: @bob Accept here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998421/extending-list-returns-none also