# 2 lists in 1 loop - Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two lists -

```
lst1 = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
lst2 = ["cherry", "grape", "pear"]
```

I want to print in this sequence-

```
apple
orange
banana
cherry
grape
pear
```

How do I do this in 1 for loop?

**EDIT:** to clarify my question - I don't want to add the two lists into a 3rd list and then print. Can I do it directly in a single for loop?

Comment: concatenate 2 lists, and print out the elements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python

Comment: to clarify my question - I don't want to add the two lists into a 3rd list and then print. Can I do it directly in a single for loop?

Comment: 2 loops: `for x in lst1: print(x)` and then `for x in lst2: print(x)` Otherwise use `itertools.chain`.

Comment: had mentioned "single for loop". anyway, it's working fine now. thanks

Comment: @access_nash could you elaborate on the solution you found acceptable?

Comment: the solution mentioned by alec_djinn works fine. Initially I had done that, but for some reason got an error - "too many items to unpack". Which is why I thought I might be doing something wrong while adding lists of different sizes (Btw, I wasn't working on the exact lists as mentioned above. I wanted something similar, so gave a simple example).

Answer (score 5):

You want to chain the lists together (not the same as creating a third list):

```
from itertools import chain

# ...
for item in chain(lst1, lst2):
    # ...
```

If you have more than 2 lists:

```
for item in chain(lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4):
```

`chain` is very efficient: it does not create a new list.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of lists you should use the unpacking operator `*` and [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
lsts = [["apple", "orange", "banana"],["cherry", "grape", "pear"]]
for item in chain(*lsts):
    print item
```

This will work if you don't know how many lists there are.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather easy question that you may solve just reading up the very beginning of the python documentation...
However... this is the answer.

```
for item in (lst1+lst2):
    print item
```

Comment: I had done this initially, however, got a message -"too many items to unpack" or something like that. But now, it's working fine. Sorry for posting such a trivial thing

Comment: It's ok.. everyone needs to start somewhere. Good luck!

Comment: Aren't the parentheses redundant?