# How to elegantly loop over multiple lists

Tags: python, loops

Say, I have two lists `a` and `b`:

```
a = [10, 20]
b = [40, 50]
```

I want to loop over all these values (`10, 20, 40, 50`) in one go.

Simply doing two loops is not what I want (repetition is ugly).

I also don't want to modify one of the lists:

```
a.extend(b)
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

So how do I do this elgantly in Python?

Comment: It's a duplicate, unfortunate that I did not find that question in the first place. Must be a wording thing.

Comment: `concat list python` first google link

Comment: @Hacketo If you're lucky enough to think about 'concatenate' as the verb.  Not trivial for non-native English speakers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/join-two-lists-in-python

Answer (score 8):

You can use [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from itertools:

```
from itertools import chain

a = [10, 20]
b = [40, 50]

for i in chain(a, b):
    print(i)
```

This will not create a new list (as `a + b` does) and is therefore more (memory-)efficient should your lists be huge.

This also works for generators and other iterables.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in a + b:
    print(i)
```

Note: I answered this myself.  Was wondering about the question, found the answer but not through SO, and felt that it should be added.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/join-two-lists-in-python

Comment: @heinst By not thinking of using terms 'join' or 'concatenate' I guess.

Comment: Searching for add or append also leads to that link