# How combine two list into list of list at python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Let's say I have:

`a = [10,14,16]`

`b = [0,1,2]`

and I want combine `a` and `b` into one list, as shown below:

```
print c
[[10, 0], [14, 1], [16, 2]]
```

I have tried to merge the two lists:

```
a + b
[10, 14, 16, 0, 1, 2]
```

but it's not same as what I want to achieve.
How can I do that in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append list to second list (concatenate lists)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is for:

```
>>> a = [10,14,16]
>>> b = [0,1,2]
>>> zip(a, b)
[(10, 0), (14, 1), (16, 2)]
```

Note that this would get you a list of tuples. In case you want a list of lists:

```
>>> [list(item) for item in zip(a, b)]
[[10, 0], [14, 1], [16, 2]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `zip` built in function. It's very efficient compared to manual implementation.

```
In [52]: c = list(zip(a,b))

In [53]: c
Out[53]: [(10, 0), (14, 1), (16, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [10,14,16]
b = [0,1,2] 
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append([a[i], b[i]])
print c
```

Or in one line:

```
print [[a[i], b[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Outputs:

```
[[10, 0], [14, 1], [16, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

using a simple for loop?

```
a = [10,14,16]
b = [0,1,2]
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    try:
        c.append([a[i],b[i]])
    except KeyError:
        c.append([a[i]])
print c
```

or by using a generator:

```
c = [ [a[i],b[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
np.array(a+b).reshape(2,3).T.tolist()
```

Comment: Think you meant `numpy` :D

Answer (score 0):

for small lists you can do a "for" loop:

```
a = [10,14,16]
b = [0,1,2]
for i in range(len(a)):
    out[i] = [a[i],b[i]]
```

Or for longer list you can use pandas to create a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.dataframe([a,b],columns = ['a','b'])
out = df.T.values.tolist()
```