# Accumulate constant value in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to sum +1 to some specific cells of a numpy array but I can't find any way without slow loops:

```
coords = np.array([[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[0,0]])
X      = np.zeros((3,3))

for i,j in coords:
  X[i,j] +=1
```

Resulting in:

```
X = [[ 1.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  3.]
     [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

`X[coords[:,0],coords[:,1] += 1` returns

```
X = [[ 1.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  1.]
     [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[numpy.at](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) is exactly for those situations.

```
In [1]: np.add.at(X,tuple(coords.T),1)

In [2]: X
Out[2]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: This is good, but a `for` loop in numba is 80 times faster :/  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57561500/125507

Comment: Deleted question?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), like so -

```
out_shape = (3,3) # Input param

# Get linear indices corresponding to coords with the output array shape.
# These form the IDs for accumulation in the next step.
ids = np.ravel_multi_index(coords.T,out_shape)

# Use bincount to get 1-weighted accumulations. Since bincount assumes 1D
# array, we need to do reshaping before and after for desired output.
out = np.bincount(ids,minlength=np.prod(out_shape)).reshape(out_shape)
```

If you are trying to assign values other than `1s`, you can use the additional input argument to feed in weights to `np.bincount`.

Sample run -

```
In [2]: coords
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 0]])

In [3]: out_shape = (3,3) # Input param
   ...: ids = np.ravel_multi_index(coords.T,out_shape)
   ...: out = np.bincount(ids,minlength=np.prod(out_shape)).reshape(out_shape)
   ...: 

In [4]: out
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't think about it. I was expecting numpy to provide a much simpler solution for such a trivial operation.

Comment: @memecs: IMHO trivial or not, I don't think it is *that* common, and that is what matters when implementing simpler solutions to problems. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [`np.histogramdd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html):

```
bins = [np.arange(d + 1) for d in X.shape]
out, edges = np.histogramdd(coords, bins)

print(out)
# [[ 1.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  3.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```