# Efficiently index 2d numpy array using two 1d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, performance, numpy

I have a large 2d numpy array and two 1d arrays that represent x/y indexes within the 2d array. I want to use these 1d arrays to perform an operation on the 2d array.
I can do this with a for loop, but it's very slow when working on a large array. Is there a faster way? I tried using the 1d arrays simply as indexes but that didn't work. See this example:

```
import numpy as np

# Two example 2d arrays
cnt_a   =   np.zeros((4,4))
cnt_b   =   np.zeros((4,4))

# 1d arrays holding x and y indices
xpos    =   [0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3]
ypos    =   [3,2,1,1,3,0,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,3,3,2,0]

# This method works, but is very slow for a large array
for i in range(0,len(xpos)):
    cnt_a[xpos[i],ypos[i]] = cnt_a[xpos[i],ypos[i]] + 1

# This method is fast, but gives incorrect answer
cnt_b[xpos,ypos] = cnt_b[xpos,ypos]+1


# Print the results
print 'Good:'
print cnt_a
print ''
print 'Bad:'
print cnt_b
```

The output from this is:

```
Good:
[[ 2.  1.  2.  1.]
 [ 0.  3.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]

Bad:
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

For the cnt_b array numpy is obviously not summing correctly, but I'm unsure how to fix this without resorting to the (v. inefficient) for loop used to calculate cnt_a.

Comment: you can about double the speed of the first for loop by changing the line in the loop to `cnt_a[xpos[i],ypos[i]] += 1`.

Comment: With `x` and `y` in a `2-column` array, here's one related [`Q&A`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863404/accumulate-constant-value-in-numpy-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could compute the **linear indices**, then **accumulate** into zeros-initialized output array with [**`np.add.at`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html). Thus, with `xpos` and `ypos` as arrays, here's one implementation -

```
m,n = xpos.max()+1, ypos.max()+1
out = np.zeros((m,n),dtype=int)
np.add.at(out.ravel(), xpos*n+ypos, 1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [95]: # 1d arrays holding x and y indices
    ...: xpos    =   np.array([0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3])
    ...: ypos    =   np.array([3,2,1,1,3,0,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,3,3,2,0])
    ...: 

In [96]: cnt_a   =   np.zeros((4,4))

In [97]: # This method works, but is very slow for a large array
    ...: for i in range(0,len(xpos)):
    ...:     cnt_a[xpos[i],ypos[i]] = cnt_a[xpos[i],ypos[i]] + 1
    ...:     

In [98]: m,n = xpos.max()+1, ypos.max()+1
    ...: out = np.zeros((m,n),dtype=int)
    ...: np.add.at(out.ravel(), xpos*n+ypos, 1)
    ...: 

In [99]: cnt_a
Out[99]: 
array([[ 2.,  1.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [100]: out
Out[100]: 
array([[2, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a bit faster than my original solution. It also has the advantage of working with any 'addition' to the original array, rather than simply adding 1 (through the last variable passed to np.add.at).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach by using 1D indexing (suggested by [@Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802273/1714410)) extended to answer the actual question:

```
>>> out = np.zeros((4, 4))
>>> idx = np.ravel_multi_index((xpos, ypos), out.shape) # extract 1D indexes
>>> x = np.bincount(idx, minlength=out.size)
>>> out.flat += x
```

`np.bincount` calculates how many times each of the index is present in the `xpos, ypos` and stores them in `x`.

Or, as suggested by @Divakar:

```
>>> out.flat += np.bincount(idx, minlength=out.size)
```

Comment: Should be faster than `np.add.at`!

Comment: @Divakar I'm not sure about that.. I guess depends on how many indexes are present and how big the output array is. If the number of indexes is large enough it might be quicker, but if the target array is huge and only few indexes are going to be modified `np.add.at` should be quicker.

Comment: Or maybe do : `out.ravel() = np.binconunt...`, to save one step? Flattened view for help?

Comment: Yes  `out.ravel() = ... ` doesn't work for some weird reason (`can't assign to function call` error in python3), but `out.flat = ...` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate on both lists at once, and increment for each couple (if you are not used to it, `zip` can combine lists)

```
for x, y in zip(xpos, ypos):
    cnt_b[x][y] += 1
```

But this will be about the same speed as your solution A.
If your lists xpos/ypos are of length n, I don't see how you can update your matrix in less than *o(n)* since you'll have to check each pair one way or an other.

Other solution: you could count (with `collections.Counter` possibly) the similar index pairs (ex: (0, 3) etc...) and update the matrix with the count value. But I doubt it would be much faster, since you the time gained on updating the matrix would be lost on counting multiple occurrences.

Maybe **I am totally wrong** tho, in which case I'd be curious too to see a not *o(n)* answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`ravel_multi_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index) funciton

```
lidx = np.ravel_multi_index((xpos, ypos), cnt_a.shape)
```

converts to "flatten" 1D indices into `cnt_a` and `cnt_b`:

```
np.add.at( cnt_b, lidx, 1 )
```

Comment: I think the problem is with indexing the same coordinates twice, not with the indexes itself (e.g. the index `[0,0]` is twice in the list).