# How to merge mutating numbers of lists into one in Python Speech Recognition?

Tags: python, list, speech-recognition, mutable

I want to merge mutable lists into one. I am using speech recognition, so the lists of words that I am getting are changing all the time. Some people said to add lists using the + operator, but every time the speaker speaks, various numbers of lists are generated. Think as if the program doesn't already know how many lists there will be every time. I have lists such as ['hi'] and ['hello'] and the next time I have lists such as ['one'], ['two'] and ['three']. I want to write a code or a function that allows to add all numbers of lists into one. Thus, I want to implement the **same** code to all numbers of lists. In the end I want to have ['hi', 'hello'] or ['one', 'two', 'three']. I am very new to Python. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Some people" were right, use +. Or explain clearly why + doesn't work for you.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking for, and why concatenating lists using `+` isn't exactly what you want. If you get different lists at different times, presumably you just want to concatenate each of those times. Have you written any code at all that you can show, to anchor your question in something concrete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append list to second list (concatenate lists)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists)

Comment: @JulienBernu  I apologize for making it unclear as I am new to coding. The reason why it might not work right now is because I want to write a function that can merge lists for as many lists as the user gives in speech recognition. What I mean by that is, I want to have a pre-existing code that when a user records and then runs the code (my code currently separates words into lists from a for loop due to something specific I want to do later), python returns a final list. So one time I can have 5 lists, and the next time I can have 32. My main goal is to concatenate them into one.

Comment: @Blckknght so far my code is list=array.split(",") #that creates separate lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: have you tried loops?

Comment: @vick please format your code using `code blocks` using backticks (\`). And why go for speech recognition as a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `+` operator is exactly what you want. For example:

```
a = ["foo", "bar"] 
b = ["bar", "got"]
c = a + b
```

prints `['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'got']`

---

If you want to add `b` to `a` use `.extend()`. You could also use `+=` but it's arguably less pythonic.

```
a = ["foo", "bar"]
b = ["bar", "got"]
a.extend(b)  # (or a += b)
print(a)
```

prints `["foo", "bar", "bar", "got"]`

**UPDATED:** With new information from the author, here's my four-line solution:

```
def merge(lists):
    result = []
    for list in lists:
        result.extend(list)
    return result
```

or, alternatively using `functools.reduce()` and the `operator` module:

```
import functools, operator
def merge(lists):
    return functools.reduce(operator.add, lists)
```

[`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) simply does:

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value. For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5). The left argument, x, is the accumulated value and the right argument, y, is the update value from the sequence.

and [`operator.add()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.add) is a shortcut for `lambda x, y: x + y`.

Comment: You see I want to create a code or function can take a various number of lists and merge them into one. In your code, you already know that there are only two lists, but what if you didn't know the total number of lists like in speech recognition? Thanks!

Comment: @vick I did just that for you in my updated answer!

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use them and see whether they work! Thank you for your help and I apologize for the late reply!

Comment: @vick don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the check mark below the voting thing if it was helpful. You should be able to test this quickly...

Comment: @vick my code had a small bug - I forgot to return the result! please try my solution again, I fixed it

Comment: @ uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I tried them separately but they didn't work, I also tried your changed version, I will see whether there is an issue with my code. Thanks again!

Comment: @vick does it work now?

Comment: @ uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I decided to go ahead and instead of using lists to use dictionaries. I will see what this can do, I think that my initial methodology and approach was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have three approaches to merge lists:

```
# using +
a = ['A']
b = [1, 2]  

a + b # ['A', 1, 2]

# using append
a.append(b) # ['A', [1, 2]]

# using extend
a.extend(b) # ['A', 1, 2]
```

What's the difference between them?
`+` operator creates new list, whereas methods mutate the one on which you call them.

Comment: I apologize for not explaining what I mean 'mutating'. What I mean by that is that I want to create a code that can take a various number of lists and merge them into one. In your code, you already know that there are only two lists, but what if you didn't know the total number of lists like in speech recognition? Thank you for your help!