# Join function in Python?

Tags: list, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and wanted to know if there was a function that joins 2 lists together? I have:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2] 
list2 = [3, 4, 5]
```

I want to quickly make a third list with `list3 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1720421/1168680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join lists you can run this:

`list3 = list1 + list2`

If you'd like to prevent duplicates in your list, use:
`list3 = list(set(list1 + list2))`

Comment: Silly me. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelBHildebrand Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.