# Database: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fmcrawler_sql.py", line 317, in <module>
    crawl(initFighter=fighter,K=4)
  File "fmcrawler_sql.py", line 114, in crawl
    write_page_to_database(initFighterURL,cur)
  File "fmcrawler_sql.py", line 292, in write_page_to_database
    write_fights_to_database(fights,cur)
  File "fmcrawler_sql.py", line 211, in write_fights_to_database
    fightId = hash(bothFighters+fight['Event'])
  TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
`
```

What is wrong with these lines?

Comment: Though you question body, does not tell much about your issue, as it not very descriptive, but it seems you are trying to concatenate a string with a list object: `bothFighters+fight['Event']` , post some code !

Comment: You need to show a sufficient amount of code that causes that error. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

read the `TypeError`: you have a string and list...what is list is obvious, so you need to take out 'Event' out the list and concatenate with the other variable - then put back into a list. Depends what you need.

```
>>> ['a']+['b']
['a', 'b']
>>> l = ['b']
>>> ['a' + l[0]]
['ab']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really see what's going on from what you've posted, but this error is pretty common. Somewhere in your actual code, you're attempting to concatenate (or add) a string and a list. The problem occurs here:

```
File "fmcrawler_sql.py", line 211, in write_fights_to_database
fightId = hash(bothFighters+fight['Event'])
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

I'm guessing that `bothFighters` is a list and `fight['Event']` is a string. Change the string to a list, and the error will probably go away. (Python allows you to "add" lists together, creating a longer list with the first-level entries of both lists).

Update with your code if you still need help.

---

[List concatenation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists)

[String concatenation basics if you ever need 'em.](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

---