# I want to split the sublists into its elements

Tags: python, list

```
import sys
su_pri=0
su_sc=0
n = int(raw_input().strip())
m=0

j=n-1
count=1
diff=0
a = []
for a_i in range(n):
    a_temp = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    a.append(a_temp)
print a
while(m<=len(a)):
    su_pri=sum(su_pri,int(a[m]))
    m=m+n+1
while(count<=n):
    su_sc=su_sc+a[j]
    j=j+n-1
diff=abs(su_pri-su_sc)
print diff
```

if n=3 then the list is

3
11 2 4
4 5 6
10 8 -12
The list is
[[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
i want to store all elements into a single list with length=9(in this case)
How can i do that???
Please tell me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Python has the "batteries included" philosophy, except if you want to flatten a list. :-/

Comment: `[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to try to flatten a list of lists in python, which I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) really helpful.

```
l =  [[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]] #the list of lists to be flattened

flattenedList = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Thanks.It really helped

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list and add them together

```
newdiff = []
for eachlist in diff:
    newdiff += eachlist
print newdiff
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
a = [[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
b = a[0] + a[1] + a[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add each element in the array to each other. [Something like this maybe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists) Hope that helps :)