# pygame will not draw rectangles

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am using python 2.7 to make a simple game and whenever I try to draw a rectangle I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/experiment.py", line 335, in 
>       (WIDTH ,HEIGHT)])
>   TypeError: invalid color argument

Here's the relevant code

```
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
grid = []
for row in range(10):
    #add empty array
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(11):
        grid[row].append(BLACK)
WIDTH = 30
HEIGHT = 30
MARGIN = 5
#starting pygame
pygame.init()

#Setting window dimensions
WINDOW_SIZE = [425,320]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
stopped = False
while not stopped:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            stopped = True
#draw grid
    for row in range(10):
        for column in range(11):
            Color = grid[row][column]
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,Color,
                             [((MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN),
                              (WIDTH ,HEIGHT)])
    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

Any assistance whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: If needs be here's the entire script in pastebin https://pastebin.com/jCXT0M4a

Pardon the quality of it

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory to me. You are supplying a `(WIDTH, HEIGHT)` tuple when a color was expected. Double-check your arguments against the formal parameters for the function call.

Comment: I checked the documentation and for
pygame.draw.rect() the parameters are: Surface, color, Rect, width=0
and the parameters for pygame.Rect() are ((left, top), (width, height))  so I don't know why it's not working

Comment: I just ran this code and added the correct import statements and didn't get any error. Would you mind adding a pastebin link to the rest of your code?

Comment: here's the entire script pardon the size of it and the quality, I'm still learning https://pastebin.com/jCXT0M4a

Comment: I'm not able to check your code on my own right now, but it does look like what you have *should* work, so I'm confused right now as well... Have you tried defining your Rect argument as a separate variable on its own and passing that in to your `pygame.draw.rect()` call? Might change where you are getting your error at and provide further clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the grid and the `Color` in the for loop and you'll see that some rows of the grid contain lists of tuples instead of just tuples. The `refresh` function causes the problem, especially these lines:

```
row1 = [right_side[0],front[0],left_side[0],back[0]]
row2 = [right_side[1],front[1],left_side[1],back[1]]
row3 = [right_side[2],front[2],left_side[2],back[2]]
```

It seems to me that row1-3 should be lists of tuples, but you create lists of lists of tuples:

```
[[(0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)], [(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)], [(255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 0)], [(0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255)]]
```

In Python 3.5 and above you can use the newest additional unpacking features that allow you to unpack lists into other lists with the star `*` operator.

```
row1 = [*right_side[0], *front[0], *left_side[0], *back[0]]
```

In other versions you can use one of [these techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists).