# can i insert of my list with List Comprehensions

Tags: python

I want to make an insert on the  List Comprehensions.
I can do it?

```
t = ['test','tes']
x = ['1','2','3','4','5']
t.insert([0,i]for i in x)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the expected output?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: t = t + x see as this was already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists

Comment: TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so `a.insert(0, x)` inserts at the front of the list, and `a.insert(len(a), x)` is equivalent to `a.append(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

If the result you're looking for is something like this

```
['test', 'tes', [0, 'test'], [0, 'tes']]
```

The code is below:

```
t = ['test','tes']
x = ['1','2','3','4','5']
t.extend([[0,i]for i in t])

print t
```

Comment: thank but I want to keep the elements as strings in the list

Comment: can you post your expected output? So I know exactly what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a list comprehension but it ends up doing extra work.  Just do it in a for loop:

```
for thing in x:
    t.insert(0, thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = ['test','tes']
x = ['1','2','3','4','5']
out = t + x
```

your out put will be ['tes','test','1','2','3','4','5','6']
or something alone those lines. python allows you to concatenate strings

Answer (score 0):

The ListItemLabel accepts only strings. I want to give it more than one element in a list, I use in ListItemLabel front str, but it does not do anything.

I do not know if it's the way you think

Python:

```
result_true = ListProperty([])

extra = self.viewedit.adapter.data 

for edit in extra: 
   if edit['active'] == True:

    app.result_true.append(edit['text'])
    #app.result_true = (edit['text'])
    print app.result_true
```

Kivy:

```
ListItemLabel:
text:str(ctx.edit)
```

Return:

['\xce\xbb\xce\xb9\xce\xb1\xcf\x83\xcf\x84\xce\xae 
   \xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xce\xbf\xce\xbc\xce\xac\xcf\x84\xce\xb1', 
   '\xcf\x83\xce\xbf\xcf\x85\xcf\x83\xce\xac\xce\xbc\xce\xb9', 
   '\xcf\x84\xcf\x85\xcf\x81\xce\xaf']