# Flatten a nested list using list unpacking in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631185/3512538) solution for merging lists such as `a = [1,2,3], b = [4,5,6]` using `res = [*a, *b]`.

Assuming I have a list of sub-lists such as `ls = [a,b]` is it possible to do something like `res = [*i for i in ls]`?

That specific line is invalid since *`SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension`*. Can something similar be done?

<s>If not, How can I create easily a list that contains all elements in sub-lists?</s>

*using python 3.5.3*

Comment: That syntax works for python3.6

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Got the same error with python3.6.1

Comment: @araknoid I'm taking about `[*a, *b]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Oh, my fault. Thanks that you have specified it in the answer.

Comment: @MSeifert I think it's not dup since I ask specifically about `[*i for i in ls]` where the _Making..._ is asking about `reduce` even though we both ask for a solution to the same problem

Comment: In that case, I think the title needed a little more clarification. I've taken the liberty to edit it.

Comment: If you're just asking about the `[*i for i in ls]` you may want to drop the part where you ask about "If not, How can I create easily a list that contains all elements in sub-lists?" because that's clearly answered in the dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't believe they've added support for list unpacking inside a comprehension yet.

As an alternative, you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([a, b]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or, a nested loop list comprehension:

```
>>> [y for x in [a, b] for y in x]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Not only 3.6, it's possible to do `[*a, *b]` in 3.5 as well (see [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/))

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Or `sum(ls, [])`. I mean, they only asked for "easily".