# How to update multiple dictionary values based on a condition?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like:

```
dict = {'A':[1,2], 'B':[0], 'c':[4]}
```

need it to look like:

```
dict = {'A':[1,2], 'B':[0,0], 'c':[4,0]}
```

What I am doing right now:

```
dict = {x: y+[0] for (x,y) in dict.items() if len(y) < 2}
```

which generates:

```
dict = {'B':[0,0], 'c':[4,0]}
```

any idea how I could avoid eliminating those who do not meet the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Try:

```
my_dict = {x: y + [0] if len(y) < 2 else y
           for (x,y) in dict.items()}
```

(as mentioned by jp_data_analysis, avoid naming variables after builtins like `dict`)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

**Note**: do not name variables after classes, e.g. use `d` instead of `dict`.

```
d = {'A':[1,2], 'B':[0], 'c':[4]}

d = {k: v if len(v)==2 else v+[0] for k, v in d.items()}

# {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [0, 0], 'c': [4, 0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'A':[1,2], 'B':[0], 'c':[4]}
new_d = {a:b+[0] if len(b) == 1 else b for a, b in d.items()}
```

Also, it is best practice not to assign variables to names shadowing common builtins, such as `dict`, as you are then overriding the function in the current namespace.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code is almost correct. Your problem is that you're filtering out any lists bigger than `2`. What you need to do instead is simply place them in the new dictionary unchanged. This can be done using the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator). It has the form `value1 if condition else value2`.
2. Also, if you want a more general way to pad every list in your dictionary to 
   be of equal length, you can use `map` and `max`.

Here is your code with the above modifications:

```
>>> d = {'A':[1, 2], 'B': [0], 'c': [4]}
>>> 
>>> max_len = max(map(len, d.values()))
>>> {k: v + [0] * (max_len - len(v)) if len(v) < max_len else v for k, v in d.items()}
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [0, 0], 'c': [4, 0]}
>>>
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that in 3.5+ you can also combine lists as follows: `{k: [*v, *[0 for i in range(max_len-len(v))]] if len(v) < max_len else v for k, v in d.items()}`

Comment: @ZaxR Yep sure, but I'm pretty sure that'd be slower than just list multiplication and concatenation.

Comment: Looking at [this analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631185/7619676) of unpacking, it seems like it might actually be faster, but I haven't really dug very deep on it.

Answer (score 1):

A generalized way:

```
d = {'A':[1,2], 'B':[0], 'c':[4]}

m = max(len(v) for v in d.values())
for k, v in d.items():
    if len(v) < m:
        d[k].extend([0 for i in range(m-len(v))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, just use [`update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
d = {'A':[1,2], 'B':[0], 'c':[4]}

d.update({x: y+[0] for (x,y) in d.items() if len(y) < 2})

d
# {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [0, 0], 'c': [4, 0]}
```

Like others have said, don't use reassign reserved names like `dict`, it's a one way street down to debugging hell.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this answer, can you please explain your rationale so I can improve it necessary? This code works and answers the question, so I'm not sure why it attracted the downvote.

Comment: I actually like your answer too but would be interested to know the downvoters idea on this.