# Store all generated list from every loop in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying out python, basically newbie. What I wanted to do is to save or store all generated list into one list and access that list later. The list is generated from a loop.

Basically my code is:

```
def doSomething():
    list = []
    ....some parsing procedures....
    ......
    ...here needed texts are extracted...
    ...so I am looping to extract all texts I need...

    for a in something:            
        list.append(a)
```

After the first execution, list is now populated...
then the program proceeds into the next page which is basically the same structure and then again invoke the doSomething function.
I hope this is now clear..

Assuming the first, second and third loop etc. generated this:

```
1st loop: [1,2,3]
2nd loop: [4,5,6]
3rd loop: [7,8,9]
```

I wanted to save these lists into one list and access it later so that:

```
alllist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you're asking "how do I add one list to another list?", there's `list1.extend(list2)` (mutating but fast) and there's `list1 + list2` (nonmutating but slower), among other approaches.

Comment: the doSomething function is run in a loop, so I am visioning and I have tried it it only replicates itself

Comment: Hmm, you lost me. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the replication problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: @Kevin just to make it clear, the program is actually a scraper, and this particular section of code parses same structure of pages so that's why the function is executed in a loop (to cover pagination)..

Comment: I have edited and elaborated the question above..hope it make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you might pass the values to another function like:

    def newFunction(args, results =[]):
        result.append(args)
        return result

then call the function that generates list:

    doSomething()
    newFunction(doSomething())

if we print newFunction(doSomething()), we will see the appended lists from doSomething function
```

Answer (score 0):

[Identation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) is important in python. Your code does not have proper Indentation. Other programming languages use { and } to group statements whereas Python uses whitespace.

```
for a in something:
    list.append(a)
for b in something2:
    list.append(b)
```

However, I would recommend using **something + something2** directly.

Comment: hi thanks but I don't see how this would result to what I posted,

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst.extend([4, 5, 6])
lst.extend([7, 8, 9])
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your first three lists from the for loop in variables, and then you can do a for loop for each list, and append it to a new list in order to get the output that you are seeking.

```
first_list = [1,2,3]
second_list =  [4,5,6]
third_list = [7,8,9]

new_list = []

for number in first_list:
      new_list.append(number)

for number in second_list:
      new_list.append(number)

for number in third_list:
      new_list.append(number)

print(new_list)
```

The output now in new_list is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: You can essentially add my code to a function, with all three of the new lists stored as global variables outside of the function, or you don't necessarily have to have a function. The choice is yours.

Comment: okay the function will loop around 400x, any easy way to initiate a new variable?

Answer (score 0):

you may use [extend](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm) method:

```
def doSomething(something):
    list = []
    for a in something:
        list.append(a)
        # ....this loop for some definite number...
    return list

allist = []
allist.extend(doSomething(smt1))
allist.extend(doSomething(smt2))
allist.extend(doSomething(smt3))
```

Comment: hi I have tried this but it returns NONE, just to make it clear, the program   is actually a scraper, and this particular section of code parses same structure of pages so that's why the function is executed in a loop (to cover pagination).. what parameter should I put in the doSomething() function?

Answer (score 0):

What you really need (I think) is what other languages might call a 'static'.  There are several solutions to this, including writing a class.  I often use a *closure* for this.

In this example, the first function called, `initial` sets-up four attributes, a `localList` (don't call a variable `list`, it masks the `list` class), `start`, and two inner functions.  References to those functions are returned (without being called) and they each have `localList` retained *in their context*.

The use of `nonlocal` (Python 3 required) is required to indicate the context of `start`.

The advantage of this is that the actual mechanism is encapsulated, and we don't have globals.  If you had variables called `localList`, `start`, `inner`, and `inner_get` elsewhere in the program they would not collide.

```
def initial():
    localList = []
    start = 1

    def inner():
        nonlocal start

        for a in range(start, start + 3):
           localList.append(a)
        start += 3

    def inner_get():
        return localList

    return inner, inner_get

# get the function references
doSomething, getIt  = initial()

for i in range(3):
    doSomething()

# get the list
print(getIt())  
# or
alllist = getIt()
```

Gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Yes its a bit complicated, but its a useful technique to get your head around if you can.

Comment: thank you, just a newbie but I will take note of this

Comment: Feel free to ask when you feel confident enough to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I had figure it out, I have to create a function that store all the lists during the loops:

```
def funcThatStoreList(args, result =[]):
    result.append(args)
```