# how to join two list of dict to single list of dict

Tags: python

I'm new to python.

I have a couple of list of dict. I just wanted to create a single list of dict.

**List 1:**

```
[{'mnemonic': u'VERS', 'value': '2.0', 'unit': u'', 'description': u'CWLS LOG ASCII STANDARD - VERSION 2.0'}, 
{'mnemonic': u'WRAP', 'value': 'NO', 'unit': u'', 'description': u'ONE LINE PER DEPTH STEP'}]
```

**List 2:**

```
[{'mnemonic': u'STRT', 'value': '3122.0', 'unit': u'FT', 'description': u'START DEPTH'}, 
{'mnemonic': u'STOP', 'value': '4968.0', 'unit': u'FT', 'description': u'STOP DEPTH'}]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ? can you please add your desired o/p ?

Comment: What difference does it make that you have lists of dicts or list of numbers? [You join them just the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: `list_1 + list_2`.

Comment: I tried append.. but its coming as `list of list of dict`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is concatinate two lists, this can be done with the `+` operator in python, like so:

```
list1 = [{'mnemonic': u'VERS', 'value': '2.0', 'unit': u'', 'description': u'CWLS LOG ASCII STANDARD - VERSION 2.0'}, {'mnemonic': u'WRAP', 'value': 'NO', 'unit': u'', 'description': u'ONE LINE PER DEPTH STEP'}]
list2 = [{'mnemonic': u'STRT', 'value': '3122.0', 'unit': u'FT', 'description': u'START DEPTH'}, {'mnemonic': u'STOP', 'value': '4968.0', 'unit': u'FT', 'description': u'STOP DEPTH'}]

list3 = list1 + list2
```