# How many copies of lists creates when 2 list concatenate with + operator?

Tags: python, list, concatenation, addition

I have read a lot info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) and [here](https://mathieularose.com/how-not-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-python/) but I still don't understand is python really make 6 copies of lists when, for example it concatenate `[1,2,3,4] + [5,6]` these 2 lists

Comment: Why would python make 6 copies of those lists?

Comment: A "copy" of the list would be the entire list. If the list contains 6 items, why would you make 6 copies of the entire list?

Comment: Do you mean 6 elements inside that list?

Comment: No, how exactly Python make two lists concatenation with + operator.
When we talk about itertools.chain it uses generator, but with + what is the exact mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't make 6 copies of the list, rather it joins or concatenates the two lists and makes them into one i.e `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

List concatenation in Python: [How to concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-concatenate-two-lists-in-python).

Comment: I have read it already, but also I found this post <https://mathieularose.com/how-not-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-python/>

Answer (score 0):

No, only the references are copied. The objects themselves aren't copied at all. See this:

```
class Ref:
   ''' dummy class to show references '''
   def __init__(self, ref):
       self.ref = ref
   def __repr__(self):
      return f'Ref({self.ref!r})'

x = [Ref(i) for i in [1,2,3,4]]
y = [Ref(i) for i in [5,6]]

print(x)   # [Ref(1), Ref(2), Ref(3), Ref(4)]
print(y)   # [Ref(5), Ref(6)]

z = x + y
print(z)   # [Ref(1), Ref(2), Ref(3), Ref(4), Ref(5), Ref(6)]

# edit single reference in place
x[0].ref = 100
y[1].ref = 200

# concatenated list has changed
print(z)  # Ref(100), Ref(2), Ref(3), Ref(4), Ref(5), Ref(200)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say there n number of list l1, l2, l3, ...
and If you add them it has only one copy on some address.

eg:

```
In [8]: l1 = [1,2,3]
In [9]: l2 = [4,5,6]

In [10]: id(l1 + l2)
Out[10]: 140311052048072

In [11]: id(l1)
Out[11]: 140311052046704

In [12]: id(l2)
Out[12]: 140311052047136
```

**id()** returns identity of an object.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id