# Why does `if None.__eq__("a")` seem to evaluate to True (but not quite)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, boolean-expression, equivalence

If you execute the following statement in Python 3.7, it will (from my testing) print `b`:

```
if None.__eq__("a"):
    print("b")
```

However, `None.__eq__("a")` evaluates to `NotImplemented`.

Naturally, `"a".__eq__("a")` evaluates to `True`, and `"b".__eq__("a")` evaluates to `False`.

I initially discovered this when testing the return value of a function, but didn't return anything in the second case -- so, the function returned `None`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

This is a great example of why the `__dunder__` methods should not be used directly as they are quite often not appropriate replacements for their equivalent operators; you should use the `==` operator instead for equality comparisons, or in this special case, when checking for `None`, use `is` (skip to the bottom of the answer for more information).

You've done

```
None.__eq__('a')
# NotImplemented
```

Which returns `NotImplemented` since the types being compared are different. Consider another example where two objects with different types are being compared in this fashion, such as `1` and `'a'`. Doing `(1).__eq__('a')` is also not correct, and will return `NotImplemented`. The right way to compare these two values for equality would be

```
1 == 'a'
# False
```

What happens here is

1. First, `(1).__eq__('a')` is tried, which returns `NotImplemented`. This indicates that the operation is not supported, so
2. `'a'.__eq__(1)` is called, which also returns the same `NotImplemented`. So,
3. The objects are treated as if they are not the same, and `False` is returned.

Here's a nice little MCVE using some custom classes to illustrate how this happens:

```
class A:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('A.__eq__')
        return NotImplemented

class B:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('B.__eq__')
        return NotImplemented

class C:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('C.__eq__')
        return True

a = A()
b = B()
c = C()

print(a == b)
# A.__eq__
# B.__eq__
# False

print(a == c)
# A.__eq__
# C.__eq__
# True

print(c == a)
# C.__eq__
# True
```

---

Of course, that doesn't explain *why* the operation returns true. This is because `NotImplemented` is actually a truthy value:

```
bool(None.__eq__("a"))
# True
```

Same as,

```
bool(NotImplemented)
# True
```

For more information on what values are considered truthy and falsy, see the docs section on [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/4909087). It is worth noting here that `NotImplemented` is truthy, but it would have been a different story had the class defined a `__bool__` or `__len__` method that returned `False` or `0` respectively.

---

If you want the functional equivalent of the `==` operator, use [`operator.eq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.eq):

```
import operator
operator.eq(1, 'a')
# False
```

However, as mentioned earlier, for *this specific scenario*, where you are checking for `None`, use `is`:

```
var = 'a'
var is None
# False

var2 = None
var2 is None
# True
```

The functional equivalent of this is using [`operator.is_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.is_):

```
operator.is_(var2, None)
# True
```

`None` is a special object, and only 1 version exists in memory at any point of time. IOW, it is the sole singleton of the `NoneType` class (but the same object may have any number of references). The [PEP8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) make this explicit:

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or
>   `is not`, never the equality operators.

In summary, for singletons like `None`, a reference check with `is` is more appropriate, although both `==` and `is` will work just fine.

Answer (score 33):

The result you are seeing is caused by that fact that

```
None.__eq__("a") # evaluates to NotImplemented
```

evaluates to `NotImplemented`, and `NotImplemented`'s truth value is documented to be `True`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html

> Special value which should be returned by the binary special methods (e.g. `__eq__()`, `__lt__()`, `__add__()`, `__rsub__()`, etc.) to indicate that the operation is not implemented with respect to the other type; may be returned by the in-place binary special methods (e.g. `__imul__()`, `__iand__()`, etc.) for the same purpose. **Its truth value is true.**

If you call the `__eq()__` method manually rather than just using `==`, you need to be prepared to deal with the possibility it may return `NotImplemented` and that its truth value is true.

Answer (score 16):

As you already figured `None.__eq__("a")` evaluates to `NotImplemented` however if you try something like

```
if NotImplemented:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

the result is

> yes

this mean that the truth value of `NotImplemented` `true`

Therefor the outcome of the question is obvious:

`None.__eq__(something)` yields `NotImplemented`

And `bool(NotImplemented)` evaluates to True

So `if None.__eq__("a")` is always True

Answer (score 1):

## Why?

It returns a `NotImplemented`, yeah:

```
>>> None.__eq__('a')
NotImplemented
>>>
```

But if you look at this:

```
>>> bool(NotImplemented)
True
>>>
```

`NotImplemented` is actually a truthy value, so that's why it returns `b`, anything that is `True` will pass, anything that is `False` wouldn't.

## How to solve it?

You have to check if it is `True`, so be more suspicious, as you see:

```
>>> NotImplemented == True
False
>>>
```

So you would do:

```
>>> if None.__eq__('a') == True:
    print('b')


>>>
```

And as you see, it wouldn't return anything.

Comment: most visually clear answer - v worthwhile addition - thank you

Comment: :) “worthwhile addition” doesn’t quite capture what I was trying to say (as you obv see) - maybe “belated excellence” is what I wanted - cheers

Comment: @scharfmn yes? I'm curious to know what you think this answer adds that hasn't already been covered before.

Comment: somehow the visual/repl things here add clarity - full demo

Comment: @scharfmn ... Which the accepted answer also has albeit the prompts have been removed. Did you upvote solely because the terminal prompts have been lazily left in?

Comment: I see what you are saying. Possibly? It’s agree it’s parasitic. But it helped me. That’s why I commented, to explain. It’s a tribute to your answer, which I have now upvoted.