# How to concatenate 2 filtered lists?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm assuming that the filtering is what's causing the issue, but I could be wrong. I'm trying to concatenate two lists, each with numbers divisible by 3 and 5. Below is my code:

```
alist = list(range(1,100))
blist = list(range(600,700))

newListA = (filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, alist))
newListB = (filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, blist))
newListC = (list(newListA), list(newListB))

list(newListC)
```

Comment: @Savaria The expected behavior is described clearly.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python list concatenate", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: My bad, will remove the comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

There are some things wrong. The main one is that you're not concatenating the lists, with the parenthesis you're creating a `tuple` of size 2 which first element will be the first list, and the second the second one. Everywhere where you are using parenthesis is a `tuple`, if you want `lists` use square brackets. To concatenate two lists, use the operator `+`.

```py
alist = list(range(1,100))
blist = list(range(600,700))
newListA = list(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, alist))
newListB = list(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, blist))
newListC = newListA + newListB
print(newListC)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! My first time posting and as you can tell I'm pretty new to this, so I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the inbuilt `extend` functionality. [Refer to Python docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
>>> alist = list(range(1,100))

>>> blist = list(range(600,700))

>>> newListA = list(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, alist))

>>> newListB = list(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, blist))

>>> print(newListA.extend(newListB))
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

To sum up and clarify, both [@Rushiraj Nenuji](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875701/5049813) and [@JosepJoestar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875594/5049813) are correct. There are two ways to concatenate lists.

One is `old_list.extend(new_list)` which takes the `new_list` and concatenates `old_list` to it.

With this method, your code could be

```
alist = list(range(1,100))
blist = list(range(600,700))

newListA = list(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, alist))
newListB = list(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, blist))
newListC = list()
newListC.extend(newListA)
newListC.extend(newListB)
# newListC is now the concatenation of newListA and newListB
```

Another way is to just use the `+` sign. So `list1 + list2` will return a value that concatenates both `list1` and `list2`.

With this method, your code could be

```
alist = list(range(1,100))
blist = list(range(600,700))

newListA = list(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, alist))
newListB = list(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 and x%5==0, blist))
newListC = newListA + newListB
# newListC is now the concatenation of newListA and newListB
```