# More efficient way of concatenating a huge amount of lists?

Tags: python

I have a huge amount of sentences (just a bit over 100,000). Each one contains on average 10 words. I am trying to put them together into one big list so I can us `Counter` from the `collections` library to show me the frequency each word occurs. What I'm doing currently is this:

```
from collections import Counter
words = []
for sentence in sentenceList:
    words = words + sentence.split()
counts = Counter(words)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing more efficiently. I've been waiting almost an hour now for this code to finish executing. I would think the concatenating is what is making this take so long since if I replace the line `words = words + sentence.split()` with `print(sentence.split())` it finishes executing in seconds. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are using a quadratic time algorithm, because on each iteration, you rebuild a whole new list. Instead, `.extend` or `.append` to words, which efficiently modifies the list in-place.

Comment: Each time you do `words + sentence.split()`, you are creating a new list with shallow copies of the items in the list.  This is going to hurt your performance.

Comment: @user3483203 it does not make shallow copies of the items in the list, it does not make copies of the items in the list at all.

Comment: if frequency of word is require then why not use dictionary ?

Comment: @prashantrana `Counter` is a dictionary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I found where I picked up that idea from.  Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python#comment13144572_1720432) comment incorrect?  Do you have a link to the documentation that clarifies?

Comment: @user3483203 in that context, I understand what they are say, but it is simply not using terminology correctly. The shallow/deep copy distinction applies to the *object being copied*, i.e. a list is either shallow or deep copied. In a deep copy, the items in the list are themselves copied recursively, in a shallow copy, the items in a list **are not copied**, that is what makes it a shallow copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't build a big, memory-hogging list if all you want to do is to count the elements. Keep updating the `Counter` object with new iterables instead:

```
counts = Counter()
for sentence in sentenceList:
    counts.update(sentence.split())
```

Comment: That makes sense, especially since I don't need the list at all later. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extend`:

```
from collections import Counter
words = []
for sentence in sentenceList:
    words.extend(sentence.split())
counts = Counter(words)
```

Or, a list comprehension like so:

```
words = [word for sentence in sentenceList for word in sentence.split()]
```

If you don't need `words` later, you can pass a generator into `Counter`:

```
counts = Counter(word for sentence in sentenceList for word in sentence.split())
```

Comment: Using `extend` made it finish almost instantly. Thanks for the help!