# Pass a set of different parameters in a list to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass a list of arguments to a function I have created.

```py
def pdftotext(params=[], layout='-layout'):
    cmd = ['pdftotext', params, '-layout']
    return cmd
```

This is how I call it:

```py
text = pdftotext(params=['-f', '1', '-l', '2'])  
return text
```

This generates below:

```
[
  "pdftotext",
  [
    "-f",
    "1",
    "-l",
    "2"
  ],
  "-",
  "-layout"
]
```

However, as you can see, an extra `[]` is added where the `params=[]` are passed.

I have tried converting the params to a string, like:

```
params = ','.join(params)
```

But this doesn't work either, as it simply joins each param and separates it with a comma.

How can I pass a set of different parameters to my function, without it creating a double list?

Comment: `cmd = ['pdftotext', params, '-layout']` -> `cmd = ['pdftotext'] + params + ['-layout']`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### For Python >= 3.5

All you need is to [unpack](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) the list of params using `*`:

```py
>>> params = ['-f', '1', '-l', '2']

>>> ['pdftotext', params, '-layout']
['pdftotext', ['-f', '1', '-l', '2'], '-layout']

>>> ['pdftotext', *params, '-layout']
['pdftotext', '-f', '1', '-l', '2', '-layout']
```

#### For earlier versions:

You can use [list concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python):

```
>>> ['pdftotext'] + params + ['-layout']
['pdftotext', '-f', '1', '-l', '2', '-layout']
```

---

It could be better to use a more dynamic approach and change `params` to be a *varargs* argument:

```py
def pdftotext(*params, layout='-layout'):
    cmd = ['pdftotext', *params, layout]  # or ['pdftotext'] + params + [layout]
    return cmd
```

And now you can pass any number of arguments:

```
>>> print(pdftotext('-f', '1', '-l', '2'))
['pdftotext', '-f', '1', '-l', '2', '-layout']
```

If you have no control on the input and want to use `params` as a list you can still do:

```py
>>> print(pdftotext(*['-f', '1', '-l', '2']))
['pdftotext', '-f', '1', '-l', '2', '-layout']
```

Answer (score 4):

firstly, be aware of defining the default argument to `params` as a list: [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/1562285)  [default](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) arguments in python can cause hard-to-find bugs

To solve your primary question, you can use [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

```
cmd = ['pdftotext', *params, '-layout']
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to concatenate your lists:

```
cmd = ['pdftotext'] + params + ['-layout']
```

when you see it in action:

```
>>> params=['-f', '1', '-l', '2']
>>> cmd = ['pdftotext', params, '-layout']
>>> cmd
['pdftotext', ['-f', '1', '-l', '2'], '-layout']
>>> cmd = ['pdftotext'] + params + ['-layout']
>>> cmd
['pdftotext', '-f', '1', '-l', '2', '-layout']
```