# Which is costlier? Mutating object or creating new object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider I have two lists in python
`a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [4, 5]`. I want to concatenate these two lists and it doesn't matter if the existing object changes.

As far as I know, we can do this in two ways as follow

`a.extend(b)`, here `a` will have the concatenated result i.e [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

`c = a + b`, `c` will have the same result.

I know that the first one mutating the same object while the second creates a new object. But which one is more costlier in terms of performance? Which method is advisable?

Comment: see this solution for a small benchmark https://stackoverflow.com/a/56407963/6260170

Comment: in practical terms this is definitely a mico-optimisation that you should not worry about

Comment: `a.extend(b)` makes you think about the state of `a` at different times. `a + b` discards the value. Perhaps you want `c = a + b`?

Comment: Yes you are right. it is `c = a + b`. Updated the question.

Comment: Well, not exactly a duplicate of the proposed (as OP clearly knows how to concat lists), but the attached answer definitely answers this...