# how to change " for loop" to list comprehension by Python3

Tags: python, list

```
tokens=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]     
for k in [m for m in tokens]:
         print(k)
```

how to change  " for loop" to just one list comprehension by Python3?

Comment: Don't. List comprehensions are for building lists. You're not trying to build a list here.

Comment: `[m for m in tokens]` is redundant. Just use `for k in tokens:`

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I think he wants to sort each elements of all 3 lists in `tokens` in a new list.

Comment: please define your expected output to get proper answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[print(j) for i in tokens for j in i]
```

Or if you want it printed in list format:

```
print([j for i in tokens for j in i])
```

**Edit:** Not sure why this got downvoted. I assume OP's asking to print all values in the nested list using list comprehensions. If they want to return a list, you could just modify the above code to assign the list to a variable.

```
tokens_flattened = [j for i in tokens for j in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question your are trying to put every element in `tokens` in a new list:

```
kList = []                 #new empty list
for m in tokens:           #main list
    for k in m:            #sub-lists
        kList.append(k)
print(kList)               #output
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple for loop to add them into one list:

```
tokens=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
token_unified = []

for k in tokens:
         token_unified += (k)

print(token_unified)
```

Output:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Answer (score 0):

```
tokens=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(*tokens, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Single line code for your expected output.

Answer (score -1):

First, try to print what your list comprehension is holding. 
`[m for m in tokens]` is nothing but your tokens. 
Now, whatever operation you want to perform **on m** for **every m** in **tokens**, perform on the first m of your list comprehension as it is a single currently selected element of the list in your loop.

The solution to your problem is as follows:

```
tokens=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[print(m) for m in tokens]
```

This will give you the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

If you want to print out single elements as a list, do the following:

```
tokens=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  
ans = []   
[ans.extend(m) for m in tokens]
print(ans)
```

It will give you the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```