# Making a 2D list into a 1D list in python

Tags: python

Making a 2D list into a 1D list in python.

Comment: use sum( [[1,2,3,4,], [5,6,7]],[])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: @Nagakiran, using `sum()` to flatten list of lists is like [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) -- unnecessarily inefficient as well as unnecessarily ugly. It should never be used, imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, give it a shot:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,], [5,6,7]]
onlyList = []
for nums in x:
  for val in nums:
    onlyList.append(val)
print(onlyList)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner with list comprehension. Basically this can be extended for any levels by adding an additional for term. Notice two `for` as its a 2d list.

```
two_dim = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
one_dim_list = [n for one_dim in two_dim for n in one_dim]

print(one_dim_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first_list= [[1,2,3,4,], [5,6,7]]
final_list=first_list[0]+ first_list[1]
print(final_list) 
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: You can either use the `code` block or Ctrl+K to format code in your answer. Also, this is not what the OP wants, it says only using `.append()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use cereja project

```
pip install cereja
```

```
import cereja as cj

cj.flatten([[1,2,3,4,], [5,6,7]])
```

Try youself:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/jlsneto/cereja/blob/master/docs/cereja_example.ipynb

See code:
https://github.com/jlsneto/cereja/blob/66b7ef86a77140429f75e4dae3606c6abacac72f/cereja/arraytools.py#L244