# Python - Pd.dataframe - sum(step, []) - "Can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

Tags: python, pandas, sum, concatenation

My task is to run a script on another machine. 
I have set up a conda environment:
Python3.6
Pandas1.0.3

The system:
Ubuntu 16.04.6
Xenial

So far I just had to adjust Python2 to Python3 code in the script, but now I am stuck with the following:

```
losses = pd.DataFrame([sum(step, []) for step in losses], colums=['Frechet Distance GAN1', 'Frechet Distance GAN2', ....])
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

I am pretty sure the villain is `(sum(step, [])` or some kind of Python2 to Python3 issue.

Comment: What did you think the `sum` part would do?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know for sure, I would guess it is a way to  concatenate two lists in Python as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56407963/13182022.

Comment: As I mentioned the code was executable and running on another machine maybe with older versions of the respective packages

Comment: Somehow I doubt that `step` is a list, so this won't work. But you should really expand the code that you've shown into a [mcve].