# Concatenating list names into strings python

Tags: python

I have lists such as:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
```

I want to put them all into a list where the list names are strings

```
list_final = ["list_1", "list_2", "list_3"]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You may wish to look at the `dict` type: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify your expected output? ``[list_1, list_2, list_3]`` is not "a list where the list names are strings". Is your desired output ``["list_1", "list_2", "list_3"]``? Are you looking for a mapping from name to list, i.e. ``{"list_1": list_1, "list_2": list_2, "list_3": list_3}``?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: try ask with exampl

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Comment: To be clear: You want to store *just* the names, *not* the values? Do you want to do this next to the assignment (e.g. inside the function defining them), or given just the lists (e.g. outside the function defining them)? Can you change the definition/assignment of the lists, e.g. to directly store them in a ``dict``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
my_lists = {
    "list_1": [],
    "list_2": [],
    "list_3": [],
}
```

The "names" ("keys" in terms of `dict`) are available as `my_lists.keys()` or by iterating `my_lists`:

```
for list_name in my_lists:
    print(list_name)
```

Or, for literally the sample given in the question:

```
list_final = list(my_lists)
```

Answer (score -1):

The below shall work..

```
list = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
names=['list_1', 'list_2', 'list_3']
list_final = dict(zip(names,list))
print(list_final)
print(list_final['list_1'])
print(list_final['list_2'])
print(list_final['list_3'])
```

If you want to just put the names in the final list, you can do this:

```
list_final_names=[]
for name in list_final:
    list_final_names.append(name)
print(list_final_names)
```

Comment: As per the question, a list of names (i.e. ``names``) is the desired *result*, not the initial setup.