# Python: How to combine several lists into one list, using no libraries

Tags: python, list, concatenation

If I have three lists in python...

```
letters_1 = ['a','b','c']
letters_2 = ['d','e','f']
letters_3 = ['g','h','i']
```

How can I combine these to one list like:

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

by using python's built in methods?

Right now I'm using numpy to concatenate lists, but I'd rather use straight Python.

```
all_letters = np.concatenate((letters_1, letters_2, letters_3))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding them together:

```
letters_1 = ['a','b','c']
letters_2 = ['d','e','f']
letters_3 = ['g','h','i']

letters = letters_1 + letters_2 + letters_3 
print(letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put `+` between them:

```
>>> letters_1 + letters_2 + letters_3 
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the python *standard* library should be fine? Then you'd use `itertools`, something like `chain` will work then.

`all_letters = list(chain(letters_1, letters_2, letters_3))`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
all_letters = letters_1 + letters_2 + letters_3
print(all_letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use + to join them together as shown in other comments.You need to know the basics and [here](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/python-tutorial-for-beginners-a-complete-guide/) is a basic tutorial for python that can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
letters_1 = ['a','b','c']
letters_2 = ['d','e','f']
letters_3 = ['g','h','i']
concatenated_list=letters_1+letters_2+letters_3
print(concatenated_list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 >>> ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

> In the above code "+" operator is used to concatenate the 3 lists into a single list.

**ANOTHER SOLUTION:**

```
 letters_1 = ['a','b','c']
 letters_2 = ['d','e','f']
 letters_3 = ['g','h','i']
 c=[] #Empty list in which we are going to append the values of list (a) and (b)

 for i in letters_1:
     c.append(i)
 for j in letters_2:
     c.append(j)
 for k in letters_3:
     c.append(k)
 print(c)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```