# Can two lists be combined to populate a Jupyter Gmaps info_box?

Tags: google-maps, jupyter, infobox

I am trying to get the pop-up box in Gmaps to show information from two different lists.  When I use 'and' to combine my info_box_content only unemployment rate show in the pop-up.  When I comment out the second list (as shown) the poverty rate info shows.  Is this possible?

```
poverty_rate = census_data["Poverty Rate"].tolist()
unemployment_rate = census_data["Unemployment Rate"].tolist()

marker_locations = census_data[['Latitude', 'Longitude']]
fig = gmaps.figure()
markers = gmaps.marker_layer(marker_locations,
   info_box_content=[f"Poverty Rate: {rate}" for rate in poverty_rate]) #and [f"Unemployment Rate: 
   {un_rate}" for un_rate in unemployment_rate
fig.add_layer(markers)
fig
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: Maybe a complete demo could help to understand the behavior better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info_box parameter takes a list with a string for each marker. You can create that string however you want. For instance, you could write:

```py
info_box_content = [
  f"Poverty Rate: {poverty_rate_value}, Unemployment rate: {unemployment_rate_value}"
  for poverty_rate_value, unemployment_rate_value
  in zip(poverty_rate, unemployment_rate
]
markers = gmaps.marker_layer(marker_locations, info_box_content)
```

Note that you can use arbitrary HTML in the template, so you can format your string nicely. See [the tutorial on markers](https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#markers-and-symbols) for examples.