# JSON data dump creating individual items from letters when updating list with new item

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

I want to update a list in JSON based on user input, but instead of creating new items from the input, it breaks the text into individual letters and creates individual items.

```
import json

def main():
    question = input("add or clear?")
    if question == "add":
        words_to_add = input("which words to add?")
        add_words("vocabulary.json", words_to_add)
    if question == "clear":
        clear_words("vocabulary.json")

def add_words(filename, words):
    with open(filename, "r+") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        data["words"].extend(words)
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

def clear_words(filename):
    with open("vocabulary.json", "w+") as f:
        data = {"words":[]}
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

example of output, when entered "new word" and "again" in separate runs:

{
"words": [
"n",
"e",
"w",
" ",
"w",
"o",
"r",
"d",
"a",
"g",
"a",
"i",
"n"
]
}
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it may be because there is no `split()` method when you get the words. I apologize for accidentally leaving that out of my other answer. Try this: `words_to_add = input("which words to add?").split()`

Comment: i should be apoligizing :-) Thanks for coaching me through the process! It works like a charm :-)

Comment: @gmdev don't forget to post your answer, so I can label it.

Comment: That's okay, there's no need for an answer. I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

It was because there is no split() method when you get the words. added:

words_to_add = input("which words to add?").split()