# how can I add a list of lists to a list in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

am trying to add a list of lists to a list

```
a = [['xx',''ee', 'yy'], [1,2,3]]

existing = [['zz', 'ss', 'ww'], [4,5,6]]
```

what is the best way add elements of `a` into the `existing` list

```
expected = [['zz', 'ss', 'ww'], [4,5,6], ['xx',''ee', 'yy'], [1,2,3]]
```

Comment: `existing.extend(a)` in case you don't need existing anymore or `expected  = a + existing `

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1720421/4046632

Answer (score 1):

Either use `extend` or `+` for concatenation as:

```
a = [['xx','ee', 'yy'], [1,2,3]]
b = [['zz', 'ss', 'ww'], [4,5,6]]
b = b + a
print(b)

a = [['xx','ee', 'yy'], [1,2,3]]
b = [['zz', 'ss', 'ww'], [4,5,6]]
b.extend(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expected = existing + a
print(expected)
```

output is :

```
[['zz', 'ss', 'ww'], [4, 5, 6], ['xx', 'ee', 'yy'], [1, 2, 3]]
```