# How to get the desired resultant list using list comprehension technique?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am having a list as:

```
list_1 = ['id', 'name', 'organization', 'notes', 'key_length', 
         'digest', 'validity_start',  'validity_end', 'country_code', 
         'state', 'city', 'organization_name',  'organizational_unit_name', 
         'email', 'common_name', 'extensions', 'serial_number', 'passphrase',
         'created', 'modified']
```

Now, I am trying to code a list comprehension to get the below list as a final result:

```
list_2 = ['id', 'name', 'organization', 'notes', 
          'key_length', 'digest', 'validity_start', 'validity_end', 
          'country_code', 'state', 'city', 'organization_name', 'organizational_unit_name',
          'email', 'common_name', 'serial_number', 'certificate', 
          'private_key', 'created', 'modified']
```

Here's what I am doing:

```
list_2 = [
            field
            for field in list_1
            if field not in {'extensions', 'passphrase'}
        ]
```

With the above LOC I am able to get the the desired list except the two fields `certificate`, & `private_key`.
For that presently I am using the insert method, but I want this to be done in the the list comprehension itself.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I didn't find either **certificate** or **private_key** in `list_1`, and thus there is not way of putting them into `list_2` using List Comprehension. List Comprehension is used to substitute [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303519/14403987) and [`filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303519/14403987) functions, but not to add something into a `list`.

Comment: @Felipe Whitaker, that is True, but we can concatenate two lists before handling the comprehensions. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python) post answers your question? It would be `for field in list_1 + ['certificate', 'private_key']`.

Comment: @Thymen sure, it is possible to do `list_2 = [...] + ['certificate', 'private_key']`, but then it is not done *inside* the list comprehension. To do it inside, he can follow [DeMO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303710/14403987)'s solution, which solves it by concatenating the two lists inside the list comprehension, like `list_2 = [... + []]`.

Comment: I guess the wording _inside_ the comprehension is a bit vague. For me using `[x for x in list_1 + ['c', 'p']]` would qualify as "inside" the comprehension, albeit not _inside_. Any way the answers  from @DeMO perfectly catches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the position in the list does not matter:

```
[field for 
field in list_1+["certificate", "private_key"] 
...
```

If it does, you can specify where you want as follows

```
[field for 
field in list_1[0:17]+['certificate','private_key']+list_1[18::]
...
```

First example joins list_1 with a list containing "certificate" and "private_key", and the second joins a splice of list_1  with the same list and the rest of list_1.

```
>>> [field for field in 
list_1[0:17]+['certificate','private_key']+list_1[18::] 
if field not in ['extensions','passphrase']]

#output
['id', 'name', 'organization', 'notes', 'key_length', 'digest',  
'validity_start', 'validity_end', 'country_code', 'state', 'city', 
'organization_name', 'organizational_unit_name', 'email',  
'common_name', 'serial_number', 'certificate', 'private_key',   
'created', 'modified']
```

Comment: Hey I am required to remove `extensions`, and `passphrase` from `list_1`, with this I am not getting the required result.

Comment: @ManishShah I added a code block that shows the full code and the output received.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna replace an item use a mapping dictionary.

```
map_dict = {'extensions': 'certificate', 'passphrase': 'private_key'}
list_2 = 
    map_dict[field] if field in {'extensions', 'passphrase'}
    else field
    for field in list_1
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As a frame challenge to you wanting to do a list comprehension, I found that, at least on the data you gave as an example, list comprehension is the slowest, LCVcode's suggestion of `list_2 = list(set(list_1) - {'extensions', 'passphrase'})` was faster, and

```
list1a.remove('extensions')
list1a.remove('passphrase')
```

was fastest. However, this last method will throw an error if the elements you are trying to remove are not present.

To add elements, you can do `list_2 = list(set(list_1) - {'extensions', 'passphrase'})+['certificate', 'private_key']`