# How to get argument to ignore part of message

Tags: python, discord.py

I just wondering how to get the if statement(`if 0 < int(message.content)< 153:`) to only test part of the message, not the full message.content.
Eg: if I put in `1s 100`, I want it to test if ONLY the 100 is within and ignore the `1s`, but also have to have the message start with `1s`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from math import floor
import math
from keep_alive import keep_alive

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")


@bot.event


async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot:
        return
  if 0 < int(message.content) < 153 & message.content.startswith('1s')  :
   await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are about {} games away from Bronze 2.  *I am not always correct*".format(math.floor((153 - int(message.content))/8 + 1)))
```

Comment: Depends on how much you want to guard it. You also haven't given enough information about all the possible formats of the message content. e.g. multiple numbers, text both before and after the number, etc. Lookup regex's.

Comment: Maybe look into [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and use it like `re.match('^1s', message)` which will match if **starts** with `'1s'`, and then you can search for `100`.

Comment: Or else, you could search for `100` `if message.content[:3] == '1s '` (as just stated by [Chuaat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303519/14403987)).

Comment: @Flakes literally all it’ll be is 1s/2s/3s and after a number

Comment: @Felipe Whitaker ty for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply add `[3:]` to `message.content`:
`0 < int(message.content[3:]) < 153`. This only works if the message starts with 3 figures before the number (in your case it's `1s` )

Comment: Hey bro thanks for answering but I copied the top [3:-1] into the part above the the .format part and after doing 1s 100 I got no output or error

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it should be [3:] @Pricysquirrl. When that's not working, can you do some little debugging to test it, like `print(message.content[3:])`

Comment: Sry I’m still not getting anything when typing 1s 100

Comment: Sry to be taking up your time but when I did the print I got a “message not defined” which confuses me

Comment: I figured the problem out! You can't use `&` before `message.content.startswith`, you have to use `and`! @Pricysquirrl.

Comment: Tysm it works!! I really hope you don’t mind if I ask two last dumb questions: Why does “and” but not “&” work and how can make your bot send a paragraph and not one line?

Comment: I guess `&` and `and` is just pythons syntax. To start a new line, write `\n`, like this:
 `await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.\nYou are about {} games away from Bronze 2.\n*I am not always correct*".format(math.floor((153 - int(message.content[3:]))/8 + 1)))`. Or what else do you mean by paragraph? @Pricysquirrl.