# Counting in one list based on another

Tags: python, list

I'd like to count the elements in y that exist in the same order than in x. So for:

```
x = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]

y = [c,a,b,z,k,f,g,d,s,t]
```

I'd want a function that returns me a 4 as 'a','b','c','d' are in y but not "e" I'd like a function that returns 4. y is random but it never has any duplicates. x is constant and len(x) = 8.
x and y are both lists of strings.

That means for:

```
x = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]

y = [c,a,k,z,k,f,g,d,s,t]
```

I'd like the function to return 1.

I've tried something with a nested loop:

```
i = 0
h = 0
for s in x:
   for t in y:
      if s == t:
        i = i + 1 #i is what I'm looking for in the end.
        h = 0
      elif h = 9:
        break
      else:
        h = h + 1
```

My idea was to count the delta from one 't' to the next 't' but I can't get it to work properly as I just can't wrap my head around the required math.
Thanks a lot for your suggestions already and please enjoy your day!

Answer (score 2):

In my previous answer, the code would throw an error when all elements of `x` were in `y` - so, here is my revised code:

```py
print(([value in y for value in x] + [False]).index(False))
```

It does the job, but it's really hard to read. Let's split it up (the comments explain what each line does):

```py
# This is our new list. In the previous code, this was a tuple - I'll get into
# that later. Basically, for each element in x, it checks whether that value is in
# y, resulting in a new list of boolean values. (In the last code, I used the map
# function with a lambda, but this is definitely more readable).

# For example, in OP's example, this list would look like
# [True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]
new_list = [value in y for value in x]

# This is the step lacking with the old code and why I changed to a list.
# This adds a last False value, which prevents the index function from throwing an
# error if it doesn't find a value in the list (it instead returns the index this
# last False value is at). I had to convert from a tuple because
# you cannot add to a tuple, but you can add to a list. I was using a tuple in the
# last code because it is supposed to be faster than a list.
new_list_with_overflow = (new_list + [False])

# This is the final result. The index function gets the first element that is equal
# to False - meaning, it gets the index of the first element where x is not in y.
result = new_list_with_overflow.index(False)

# Finally, print out the result.
print(result)
```

Hopefully this explains what that one line is doing!

Some more links for reading:

- [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples)
- [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)
- [Python Docs on List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

---

Here is another (arguably less readable) code snippet:

```py
print((*(value in y for value in x), False).index(False))
```

A benefit of this code is that it uses tuples, so it is faster than the previous code, with the drawback of being a bit harder to understand. It also is not supported by older versions of python. However, I can leave this as an exercise for you to figure out! You might want to check out [what the * does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631185/11483682).

---

**EDIT:** This is the new answer. The code below only works when all elements of `x` are not in `y` - otherwise, it throws an error. Also, these solutions are just more readable.

A "pythonic" one-liner:

```
print(tuple(map(lambda value: value in y, x)).index(False))
```

Comment: Wow this one is very impressive! I've never worked with `map` nor `lambda` nor do I quite understand how .index(false) makes sense but I will try to figure it out! Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, I do have another question. I was wondering why you chose a tuple instead of a list? Is it because I said that y is random and tuple handles different data types? I've tried your function with `list(...)` instead and it worked, too.

Comment: Okay. I've done a bit further research. Your function posts an error if all elements of x are represented in y. I've solved this with the following code:
`while True:  try: indexes = tuple(map(lambda value: value in y, x)).index(False) break except: indexes = len(x) break`

Comment: @Difio Oh, I forgot to test that! Here, I can edit my question with a better solution and an explanation as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your function needed:

```
def counter(x, y):
    print("_" * 50)
    print("x: " + str(x))
    print("y: " + str(y))
    for i, letter in enumerate(x):
        if letter not in y:
            break
    print("i: " + str(i))
    return i

counter(
    ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"], 
    ["c","a","b","z","k","f","g","d","s","t"]
)
counter(
    ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"], 
    ["a","b","z","k","f","g","d","s","t"]
)
counter(
    ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"], 
    ["c","a","b","z","k","f","g","d","s","t", "e"]
)
```

return:

```
__________________________________________________
x: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
y: ['c', 'a', 'b', 'z', 'k', 'f', 'g', 'd', 's', 't']
i: 4
__________________________________________________
x: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
y: ['a', 'b', 'z', 'k', 'f', 'g', 'd', 's', 't']
i: 2
__________________________________________________
x: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
y: ['c', 'a', 'b', 'z', 'k', 'f', 'g', 'd', 's', 't', 'e']
i: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile
result = len(list(takewhile(lambda item : item in y, x)))
```

It takes every item in `x` starting from the first item in `x` until the condition `lambda item : item in y` is no longer satisfied.