# How do I concatenate subarrays of a list into one list; ie create a flat list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Assume I have array  `arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

How do I concatenate this array into one array, such as `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
arr2 = []
for x in arr:
  arr2+= x
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic approach will be a double loop list comprehension

```py
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print([j for i in arr for j in i])
```

alternatively

```py
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(sum(arr,start = []))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools`

```
import itertools
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
arr2=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arr))
```