# Read a text file and return punctation as a string

Tags: python

I want to create a program in Python which reads the text from a text file and returns a string where everything except punctuation (period, comma, colon, semicolon, exclamation point, question mark) has been removed. This is my code:

```
def punctuation(filename):
    
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
        s = ''
        punctations = '''.,;:!?'''
        for line in f:
            for c in line: 
                 if c == punctations:
                      c.append(s)
    return s
```

But it only returns `''`, I have also tried with `s = + c` instead of `s.append(c)` since append might not work on strings but the problem still remains. Does anyone want to help me find out why?

**How it should work:**

If we have a text file named `hello.txt` with the text "Hello, how are you today?" then `punctation('hello.txt')` should give us the output string `',?'`

Comment: ```if c == punctations:``` compares one char to the whole ```punctations ``` variable. You should replace this by ```if c in punctations:```. And i don't get the ```c.append(s)``` line. You'll get an error (c seems to be a string), and you want to add a char to s.

Comment: I guess `c == punctutations` will never be `True` since `c` is a character and `punctations` is a longer string. Would you try `if c in punctutations:` instead?

Comment: Thank you both! I had missed this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `c == punctutations` will never be `True` since `c` is a character and `punctutations` is a longer string. Another problem is that `append` doesn't work on strings, you should use `+` to concat strings instead.

```py
def punctuation(filename):
    
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
        s = ''
        punctations = '''.,;:!?'''
        for line in f:
            for c in line: 
                 if c in punctations:
                      s += c
    return s
```

Answer (score 3):

You were comparing each character to the whole string when you should have been checking if it belonged in `punctuations`. Also, `append` was not the appropriate method here, because you were not returning a list instead you could concatenate the characters into `s`.

```
def punctuation(filename):
    
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
        s = ''
        punctations = '''.,;:!?'''
        text = f.read()
        words = text.split()
        for line in text:
            if line in set(punctations):
                s+=line
    return s
```

Another approach you could take to check if it's a symbol is the `isalnum()` method since it will consider all values that aren't characters or numbers incase you miss any symbols out.

```
if line!= " " and line!= "\n" and not line.isalnum():
```

Comment: To express distinct symbols the `set` is a great idea. The explanation of issues is helpful, it solves at conceptual level, e.g. "belonged _in_ punctuations"

Comment: Thanks. Although I think the `isalnum()` method could be more suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues

Some statements seem to have issues:

```py
if c == punctations: # 1
    c.append(s)  # 2
```

1. A single character is never equal to a **string of many characters** like your `punctations` (e.g. `'.' == '.?'` is never true). So we have to use a different boolean comparison-operator: `in`, because a character can be an element in a collection of characters, a string, list or set.
2. You spotted already: since `c` is a *character* and `s` a *str* , **not lists** we can not use method `append`. So we have to use `s =  s + c` or shortcut `s += c` (your solution was almost right)

#### Extract a testable & reusable function

Why not extract and test the part that fails:

```py
def extract_punctuation(line):
    punctuation_chars = set('.,;:!?') # typo in name, unique thus set
    symbols = []
    for char in line: 
        if char in punctuation_chars:
            symbols.append(char)
    return symbols


# test
symbol_list = extract_punctuation('Hello, how are you today?')
print(symbol_list)  # [',', '?']
print(''.join(symbol_list))  # ',?'
```

#### Solution: use a function on file-read

Then you could **reuse that function** on any text, or a file like:

```py
def punctuation(filename):
    symbols = []
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
        symbols + extract_punctuation(f.read())
    return symbols.join()
```

Explained:

1. The default result is defined first as empty list `[]` (returned if file is empty).
2. The list of extracted is added to `symbols` using `+` for each file-read inside `with` block (here the whole file is read at once).
3. Returns either empty `[].join()` giving `''` or not, e.g. `,?`.

See:
[How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

#### Extend: return a list to play with

For a file with multiple sentences like `dialogue.txt`:

```
Hi, how are you?
Well, I am fine!
What about you .. ready to start, huh?
```

You could get a list (ordered by appearance) like:
`[',', '?', ',', '!', '.', '.', ',', '?']`
which will result in a string with ordered duplicates:
`,?,!..,?`

To extend, a list might be a better return type:

1. **Filter unique** as set: `set( list_punctuation(filename) )`
2. **Count frequency** using pandas: `pd.Series(list_punctuation(filename)).value_counts()`

```py
def list_punctuation(filename):
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
        return extract_punctuation(f.read())


lp = list_punctuation('dialogue.txt')

print(lp)
print(''.join(lp))

unique = set(lp)
print(unique)

# pass the list to pandas to easily do statistics
import pandas as pd
frequency = pd.Series(lp).value_counts()
print(frequency)
```

Prints above *list*, *string*. plus following *set*

```
{',', '?', '!', '.'}
```

as well as the ranked frequency for each punctuation symbol:

```
,    3
?    2
.    2
!    1
```

Today I learned - by playing with

- punctuation & Python's data structures