# How can I add an item into an exisitng list (Python)

Tags: python, list

I try to write a code for a blackjack game. In the case, the player wishes to draw a new card, I want to write a code that randomly picks a card(number) from a list and inserts into the deck of the player.
The code I used was the following:

```
cards = [11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10]
players_card= random.choices(cards, k=2)
```

in case the player wants to draw a new one:

```
 players_card.append(random.choices(cards, k=1))
```

the result however is:

```
[6, 3, [x]]
```

So it inserts me a list instead of a number and so I cannot further calculate with it. Do I need to use another function instead of .append or what kind of logic am I missing?

Comment: For `k=1` you may also use `choice()` (no `s`) to get a single element, or use `.extend()` to append a list.

Answer (score 1):

the fact is that random.choices(cards, k=1) returns a list.

try using:

```py
players_card = players_card + random.choices(cards, k=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`random.choices` returns a list of random elements from an iterable, with replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

Either use `+=` ([to add two lists together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)):

```py
players_card += random.choices(cards, k=1)
```

Or, use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to only get one element:

```py
 players_card.append(random.choice(cards))
```

Answer (score 1):

`players_card.extend(random.choices(cards, k=1))`

Comment: Might you please [edit] your post to provide an [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how it answers the question and differs from other, similar answers?  Doing so would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem.  It would also make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`random.choices(cards, k=1)` returns a list having only one value.
You can concatenate the two lists like this

```
players_card = players_card+random.choices(cards, k=1)
```

OR you could also do

```
 players_card.append(random.choices(cards, k=1)[0])
```