# Difference between Model(inputs=[input],outputs=[output1,output2]) and Model(inputs=[input],outputs=[output1]+output2) in KERAS?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, tf.keras, attention-model

[Please check out the last line of the code](https://gist.github.com/AdiShirsath/725a56b80c1647195d0d4b8aa54cc903#file-machine-translation-attention-inference-py)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post the relevant code *here*, *not* in external repos; see how to create a [mre[.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code from your link, the model outputs is defined as `[decoder_outputs2] + dec_states2`, where `decoder_outputs2` seems to be an output from a `Dense` layer, and `dec_states2` is a list of outputs from some other layers (`dec_states = [decoder_state_h, decoder_state_c]`). Therefore both `[decoder_outputs2]` and `dec_states2` are python lists and can be concatenated using `+` (see [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)).

Doing `outputs=[decoder_outputs2] + dec_states2` means the model will have three outputs. It is equivalent to specifying `outputs=[decoder_outputs2, decoder_state_h, decoder_state_c]`, the latter option definitely being more readable.

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering such off-topic questions, as advised in the [community guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/4685471).