# What is an easy way to flatten a 2D-list without For Loops?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Looking to flatten a 2D list into a 1D list without `for loops` or other packages...

```
A = 1
B = [3, 4, 5]
C = A

list = [A, B, C]
```

> shown: list = [1, [3, 4, 5], A]

This is what's desired

> Desired: list = [1, 3, 4, 5, A]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Asterisks allow for the unpacking of iterables into a list/tuple

```
list = [A, *B, C]
```

Will yield:

> list = [1, 3, 4, 5, A]