# Python equivalent of vector::reserve()

Tags: c++, python

I am looking for the Python equivalent of the C++ vector::reserve().  I don't know how big the list is going to be ahead of time, but I know it's going to be fairly large, and I want to avoid as many resizings as possible as the list is being grown inside a deep inner loop.

The only solution I've come up with so far is very cumbersome compared to the vector::reserve() idiom.  That solution is to pre-create the list using [None]*K, tracking the size of the list in a separate counter, appending or setting items into the list as need be, then copying a slice of the list once it's fully constructed.  Is there any alternative?

Comment: Python lists are built to have fast appends. I don't think you're going to save anything over simply appending to the list inside a loop with your approach.

Comment: Here are some suggestions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537086/reserve-memory-for-list-in-python

Comment: Python doesn't resize after every `append`, it does it periodically, which seems to be what you're trying to do. Let Python do it for you.

Comment: Python lists are more like C++ lists or deques than vectors in that there's no requirement for the elements to be in contiguous memory, since there are no pointers.

Comment: Note that the benchmark in Di Zou's question assumes that you know the full size beforehand and thus can avoid all resizing (and even then it's a relatively small difference). In your case, the resizing that happens internally will likely beat manual (read: Python-level) resizing any day of the week. It's only when can avoid *any* reallocation that it makes sense.

Comment: The usual replacement is `# TODO - figure out how to pre-size the list if it turns out to be a performance bottleneck`

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: That's wrong. Plain and simply wrong. There are *only* pointers (to `struct PyObject`), and those are stored sequentially and need to be copied during resizing. The objects don't need tobe copied, true, but that's more because they're reference types anyway. What Python calls a `list` is actually pretty close to a `std::vector`. It it was a linked list or deque, it would have quite different performance characteristics for many operations (like accessing an item in the middle or appending at the beginning).

Comment: @MikeDeSimone - in the CPython implementation, list is in fact a contiguous block of references/pointers to Python objects, and resizing time may be an issue, though the time needed to construct the individual objects in the list usually swamps that.

Comment: OK, sorry, I thought we were talking about Python by itself, not CPython bindings and internals. What I meant was that the `[]` operation in Python does not require one parameter to be a pointer as it does in C, and there are no unary `*` or `&` operators for creating or dereferencing pointers, because Python (as in the code you put in a `.py` file) doesn't have pointers. ... I need to get better about phrasing things more clearly so people don't misinterpret them into something scandalous.

Comment: We *are* talking about Python ;) CPython's implementation is just an example, in many things (including those mentioned here) can only be implemented sensible in roughly the way CPython does it. I see what you're saying now - though there's still a few details I could nitpick about ;) - but I don't see how it is relevant to the question. That is, unless you tried to state that resizing a list won't copy the objects contained in there but only references to them. But I take that as given - Python objects are *always* reference types (as in, can only be accessed through references/pointers).

Comment: Just how large does this list get?  In general how long is the program taking?  How long is acceptable?

Comment: If you want to do this kind of optimization, Python might not be the language for you, to be perfectly honest. Or at least, you could deal with the data through something like NumPy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Create a list with initial capacity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311775/python-create-a-list-with-initial-capacity)

Comment: @NilsvonBarth, reserve() != initial capacity.

Comment: @AndrewProck, in this case they're almost identical, since you only need one initial call, and the basic question is identical: both questions want a list with enough capacity to hold the expected elements, to avoid resizings: “I want to avoid as many resizings as possible”. Formally, `[std::vector::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)` “Request a change in capacity: Requests that the vector capacity be at least enough to contain n elements.” If you need other features (repeated manual resizing, say), please state them in the question.

Comment: @NilsvonBarth I appreciate your attempts to help, but marking a duplicate when it's not is not constructive.

Comment: @AndrewProck What else are you asking for? There is no reserve in Python. For initial capacity, see other question. Done.

Answer (score 8):

For the heck of it, I did some performance testing:

```
def foo(n):
  x = []
  for y in xrange(n): x.append(y)

def bar(n):
  x = [None] * n
  for y in xrange(n): x[y] = y

def baz(n):
  # This is obviously silly; we could just do range(n)
  # but this way makes for a fairer test
  x = [y for y in xrange(n)]

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:foo(1000000), number=10)
1.761765391970215
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:bar(1000000), number=10)
0.79829286962450396
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:baz(1000000), number=10)
0.9904259479906159
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:foo(10000), number=1000)
1.3354106457664443
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:bar(10000), number=1000)
0.70596751821813086
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:baz(10000), number=1000)
0.58049759117432131
```

Answer (score 7):

Similarly to `std::vector`, CPython's `list` already preallocates more elements than is required and then grows that allocated space in a manner that gives `O(1)` amortized appends. I would therefore leave it at that until I could prove through profiling this is indeed a bottleneck.

**edit:** You mention in the comments that you've already done the profiling. In such a case, pre-allocating `[None]*n` might be a sensible thing to try to see if it's really the repeated reallocations that are the bottleneck.

If your array is numeric, I would encourage you to take a look at [NumPy](https://numpy.org/).

Comment: @drewster You should add profiling results to your question, and explain why you think it's growing the list that is the bottleneck, and not just the rest of the `append` operation.

Answer (score 3):

To put it plainly, you can create a pre-sized list by the following:

```
lst = [None] * N # where N = size of list
```

Of course, you'd have to set each index manually (as opposed to append()) and keep track of the last index you used.

If you *should* do that, however, is another question (which our comrades have done a good job of answering).