# How to preallocate a buffer of certain size in Python?

Tags: python, performance

I have an use case where I will want to combine multiple chunk of buffers into a single buffer. In case of C/C++/Java I will preallocate a buffer whose size is the same as the combined size of the source buffers, then copy the source buffers to it. How can it be done in Python in similar way. I want to avoid creating multiple smaller intermediate buffers that may have a bad impact on performance.

Comment: As "buffer" you mean an array? Please provide more information

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reserve memory for list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537086/reserve-memory-for-list-in-python)

Comment: I posted the answer. Although I think it's not a very good practice in python to allocate the size of the array beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do what you wanna do is:

```
initial_value = None # or 0, False, etc.
size = 10 # Or the size of your buffer
buffer = size * [initial_value]
```