# Python type casting when preallocating list

Tags: python, mypy, typing

This question might already have an answer, so please guide me to one if you know any. I couldn't find one myself, though this question feels like a common one.

So, consider the following pattern:

```py
arr = [None] * n
for i in range(n):
    # do some computations
    # ...
    # even more computations
    arr[i] = MyClass(some_computed_value)
```

So far so good, I tend to use this pattern from time to time. Now, let us be thorough in our attempt to provide all the code with type annotations. The problem is that we preallocate our array with `None`s, so it has the type `list[None]`. But we want it to be `list[MyClass]`. How do we proceed?

The most straightforward solution is making it optional:

```py
arr: list[Optional[MyClass]] = [None] * n
```

This solves the type checker issue, but now it's our issue since that `Optional` prohibits us from performing even basic operations on the result

```py
arr[0].my_method()
# error: NoneType has no attribute "my_method"
```

Long story short, I end up with the following pattern:

```py
arr_: Any = [None] * n
for i in range(n):
    # ...
    arr_[i] = MyClass(some_computed_value)
arr = typing.cast(list[MyClass], arr_)
```

This is ugly, inconvenient, barely readable and boilerplate. What do you do?

Comment: Before jumping through non-idiomatic hoops, are you aware that `append()` has an amortized performance of O(1)? The preallocation May not be worth it.

Comment: @Mark if that's a hot spot, it can double performance like it did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537086/reserve-memory-for-list-in-python)

Comment: @Mark so you're saying it behaves like `std::vector` from stl? Like, expanding exponentially after being filled up? If so, it should result in sth like logarithmic performance. Then yeah, it should be good as it is.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov If you're referring to the accepted answer from that question, I'd be careful drawing performance conclusions from a 2009 Python 2 benchmark. Re-running those benchmarks with Python3.11 only results in a 10% difference (32.7 vs 29.4 msec).

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov That's just to *build* the list; the contribution of that 50% reduction may be a small, nearly insignificant improvement to the overall program that *uses* the final list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lie to your type checker when you first initialize `arr` to "trick" it that `arr` never contains `None` entries. For the purposes of static type checking, `arr` will be a `list[MyClass]`, even though it briefly contains `None` entries at runtime. You of course assume responsibility for making sure that this assumption plays out.

For example,

```
from typing import cast, reveal_type

n = 1000

arr: list[int] = [cast(int, None)] * n
# or alternatively
arr: list[int] = [None] * n # type: ignore

for i in range(n):
    arr[i] = i

reveal_type(arr)
reveal_type(arr[0])
```

passes type checking with both `mypy` and `pyright`, and outputs

```
# mypy
tmp.py:9: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.int]"
tmp.py:10: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

# pyright
file.py
  file.py:9:13 - information: Type of "arr" is "list[int]"
  file.py:10:13 - information: Type of "arr[0]" is "int"
0 errors, 0 warnings, 2 informations
```

Comment: Oh, wow, i didn't think of it. Really, we can cast from the very beginning. And it's better than my approach. But it still requires casting or ignoring... Ignoring improves readability, so maybe one should use it instead of casting? Anyway, that's a good point you got here

Comment: Can you cheaply create *an* instance of `MyClass`, and use that instead of `None` to initialize the list? Then there is no issue with assigning new (more expensive) instances of `MyClass` to the list. (E.g., `arr = [MyClass(0)] * n`)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a class definition:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = id(self)
    def my_method(self) -> int:
        return self._id
```

...and we'll have...

```
N = 5
```

Now we can construct an appropriately annotated list as follows:

```
arr: list[MyClass|None] = [None] * N
```

In other words, the list can have elements that are either None or a reference to a MyClass class.

Let's assign an instance to the first element...

```
arr[0] = MyClass()
```

Now we can iterate over the list and call my_method() as follows:

```
for mc in arr:
    if mc is not None:
        print(mc.my_method())
```

Comment: Maybe you’re saying this implicitly, but just to be clear, in all code that uses elements from the list, will you need to explicitly check for `None`?

Comment: @Mark yes, I think that's the issue. We can of course check every time whether a list element is None or not, but, well, it's clear as day that it's never None. So I would personally refrain from using said pattern.

Comment: If the list is annotated as potentially containing either None or MyClass and if you're using Pylance, you'll get a complaint if you don't test for None. The way you construct the list may mean that there's no runtime/functional reason to test for None so you could just ignore any warnings in your IDE or suppress the warning with *# type: ignore*

Comment: @DarkKnight yeah, we can do this, but it feels too... hacky.

Comment: @heinwol It is not a hack in any sense of the word