# how to define a list with predefined length in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to do the following :

```
l = list()
l[2] = 'two'
```

As expected, that does not work. It returns an out of range exception.

Is there any way to, let say, define a list with a length ?

Comment: Make a list with initial values. e.g `[None]*5` ?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5533598/1982962)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
  values = [None]*1000
```

In place of 1000 use your desired number.