# Allocate memory for a list

Tags: python, list, memory

Can I set the capacity of a `list` when I already know the size the list will eventually have? I'm trying to avoid Python reallocating memory when `append`ing items to it.

In the constructor, setting `capacity`, `size`, `length` or `len` does not work.

```
def merge_lists(a, b):
    result = list(capacity=len(a) + len(b))
    ...
```

*Edit:* ...without having to actually add any elements.

Comment: Related worth reviewing: [Python - Create a list with initial capacity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311775/python-create-a-list-with-initial-capacity)

Comment: If you're really looking for speed, consider numpy for numerical arrays or for "C-like" numerical arrays: https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It feels like premature optimization to me.

Comment: Consider a fixed size deque. I can't say for sure it will offer any optimization though.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want 10 elements, you can do:

```
l = [None] * 10
```

or

```
l = range(10)
```

Comment: OK, but I need the list to be empty.

Comment: Using [None] * 10 basically creates an empty list as None provides that. ("Assigning a value of None to a variable is one way to reset it to its original, empty state.")

Comment: It seems that OP is after something like reserve in c++ for a vector. Where you can reserve memory for e.g. 10 elements, without affecting vector's size. Both our solution indicate that lists have length, as they are de-facto not empty.

Comment: Yes, but after `l.append(42)` it will be `l.index(42) == 10` instead of `0`.

Comment: Indeed, in C++ you can play around with malloc to create dynamic sized objects. In python you do not have the same liberty. I think this is the best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is this:

```
In [1]: result = [0]*100

In [2]: len(result)
Out[2]: 100
```

This will make result hold 100 elements, before you do anything with it.

Comment: OK, but I need the list to be empty.

Comment: So, the answer is most likely no. Python is not c++, where you can manage memory allocation by yourself. Maybe there are some non-standard containers, e.g. [blist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/?), that can do it.